# su options - running command as another user

Tags: bash, scripting, su, sudo

I was wondering how to run a command as another user from a script.

I have the script's owner set as root. I also have the following command being run within the script to run the command as the hudson user:

```
su -c command hudson
```

Is this the correct syntax?

Comment: For other googlers:  some users might have this ability disabled on purpose. You can run `sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep user-abc`. If you see something like this: `user-abc:x:994:994::/home/user-abc:/bin/false` then it won't work. That's because the last part "`/bin/false`" means that there is no shell for that user.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes. Here's the `--help`:

```
$ su --help
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
```

And some testing (I used `sudo` as I don't know the password for the `nobody` account)

```
$ sudo su -c whoami nobody
[sudo] password for oli: 
nobody
```

When your command takes arguments you need to quote it. If you don't, strange things will occur. Here I am —as root— trying to create a directory in /home/oli (as oli) *without* quoting the full command:

```
# su -c mkdir /home/oli/java oli
No passwd entry for user '/home/oli/java'
```

It's only read `mkdir` as the value for the `-c` flag and it's trying to use `/home/oli/java` as the username. If we quote it, it just works:

```
# su -c "mkdir /home/oli/java" oli
# stat /home/oli/java
  File: ‘/home/oli/java’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 5817025     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     oli)   Gid: ( 1000/     oli)
Access: 2016-02-16 10:49:15.467375905 +0000
Modify: 2016-02-16 10:49:15.467375905 +0000
Change: 2016-02-16 10:49:15.467375905 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: With `-c` option, does `su` invoke a shell and execute the command in the shell? Or does it execute the command without additional shell?

Comment: It's a sub-shell. Try it with sleep and look at pstree, group, etc

Comment: It doesn't load the user's environment variables

Answer (score 70):

Note: "I have the script's owner set as root" doesn't do anything; even if you have the setuid bit set it [still doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

---

Assuming you're actually running the script as root, however, you can use `sudo`. `su` is primarily for switching users, while `sudo` is for executing commands as other users. The `-u` flag lets you specify which user to execute the command as:

```
sudo -u hudson command
```

Comment: Many times I have faced (on the systems where sudoers is well-administered) that trying to use `sudo` you can just get this: `root is not in the sudoers file`. Which makes `su - <username> -c "command to run"` the only option.

Comment: Quotes not needed when executing a non-trivial command. (E.g., `sudo -u kilgore mv this that`)