# Running some parts of a script as an unprivileged user with shell environment

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, su

I am creating an instance configuration script that sets up a machine.

I am running the script via sudo i.e. `sudo run.sh`. Most of the steps require root access but some of the script's steps do no require root access and I prefer running them as the unprivileged user who ran the sudo.

Inside the script running with sudo, I am trying to do

```sh
sudo -i -u username sh -c 'echo $MY_ENV'
```

Since `.bashrc` contains `export MY_ENV=something` I expect the above command to print "something"

How can I temporarily switch inside the script to the other user to run commands that **include the user's shell env** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [su options - running command as another user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/su-options-running-command-as-another-user)

Comment: @jasonwryan I've seen that but it says nothing about including the user's env vars as well

Comment: @Michael: Take a look at `su`'s option `-`.

Comment: Try removing "sh -c" arguments.

Comment: @jasonwryan - This isn't about `sudo` or `su`, I think. Michael - when you call `sh` you don't get `bashrc` doing anything - even if `sh` is a link to `bash`. You can do `ENV=~/.bashrc sh -c 'cmd'` though, maybe. A possible issue with *that* though *is* `sudo`. You can do `sudo env - ENV=~/.bashrc sh -c 'cmd`. Though I'm not positive if it will correctly work with `-c` - have to check that. Oh. jasonwryan - maybe it is about `sudo` after rereading the question. I guess we're talking about `.bashrc` influencing the command before it is run, not a shell's init file.

Comment: @Cyrus tried any combination of that, couldn't get it to work, still would not print what's in the `.bashrc` file

Comment: Try this: `su USERNAME -c "bash -i -c 'echo foo'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bashrc` is executed only by interactive shells, not by scripts¹. It's the wrong place to define environment variables. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) and [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

You can tell bash to read `.bashrc` explicitly. Of course you'll have to execute `bash`, not `sh` which could be a different shell:

```
sudo -i -u username bash -c '. `~/.bashrc; echo "$MY_ENV"'
```

But it's a bad idea because `.bashrc` files are likely to contain things that assume that they're executed on a terminal and that spend time setting up key bindings, aliases, prompts, etc.

The sane solution is to put environment variable definitions where they belong, in `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`.

¹  <sub>Except when bash is called by `sshd` for some weird reason.</sub>