# How to Switch user and run a command as that user?

Tags: linux, scripting, command

I wanted to set up a script that switches users and runs that command as that other user.

so example

sudo su myFavoriteUser && /run/command/as/myFavoriteUser

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sahr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [su options - running command as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/su-options-running-command-as-another-user)  .... always do research before asking a question ... did you google ...  bash execute script as another user ... why do research  ?  it makes you far more productive and independent

Comment: I agree with the above comment but since Sahr is a new user, I'll suggest to him to look at the option `-c` for `su`