# su Options (running a command as another user)

Tags: linux, command-history, su

Hello StackExchange community,
This post relates to [su options - running command as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/su-options-running-command-as-another-user) (however I cannot make comments yet, as I have created a profile to ask this specific question below).

I would like to ask the following question (as Google cannot find the answer for me).

I have a command, which is the following:
`sudo su - usertwo -c 'mv /home/usertwo/file1.txt /home/usertwo/file2.txt'`

The above command is executed by `userone`.
I would like the command to also appear in `.bash_history` of `usertwo`.

Is there a way I can "forward" the entry in .bash_history of userone into usertwo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A better command is

```
sudo -Hu usertwo mv file1.txt file2.txt
```

But in either this case or yours the command isn't run interactively as `usertwo` so it won't go into that user account's `.bash_history`.

You can create a (horrible) workaround, though, by forcibly enabling history tracking:

```
sudo -Hu usertwo bash -c '
    set -o history; HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history"; history -n
    mv file1.txt file2.txt
'
```