# How to use the "setuid" bit?

Tags: permissions, non-root-user, privileges, setuid

I created a small script as the root user...

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/shadow
```

and set the **setuid** bit and placed it within the guest folder. When I ran the script as *guest*, it showed permission denied. Why? I had the root setuid bit set on it which should execute it with the root privileges as root user created the script.

Comment: Despite what the answers from the purported dupe say, if you REALLY want it, you [can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517166/308316) use setuid scripts on Linux. Even making them unreadable, which regular scripts can't be.

Comment: @mosvy I just tried that trick on my Debian 9. Indeed the unreadable script is executed, but the suid bit of the interpreter script remains ignored. With which system could you verify that?

Comment: @Philippos You either have your filesystem mounted nosuid or it's an effect of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660). I have "fixed" my example for the latter case ;-)

Comment: Latter case here. And as far as I can see, it won't work with `/bin/sh` being a current `dash`?

Comment: @Philippos Since I pass the `-p` option to `sh`, it does work with `/bin/sh` being either a current `dash` or `bash` (as that from debian buster). The `-p` option will cause an error with older versions of `dash` (or with busybox), I've added a note about that. (btw, I don't get notifications about comments without the at-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the SUID bit is ignored on interpreted scripts. If you wrote a C program that executed the same command, then it would work.

Comment: So if I set the setuid bit on the "cat" command itself in "/usr/bin/", would it work then?

Comment: Yep, that would work too

Comment: But it sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Henrik Yep that too

Comment: Of course I won't do it lol. I just wanted to be sure whether it would work or not :)