# Permissions to a script in a folder acting weird

Tags: shell-script, executable, chmod

I created a script, and I want it to be rwx only by root. All other can only x. What I have now

```
[root@localhost /]# chmod 755 scripts/ -v
mode of 'scripts/' retained as 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
[root@localhost /]# chmod 711 scripts/macchange -v
mode of 'scripts/macchange' retained as 0711 (rwx--x--x)
```

And I think all is good here. If I go with my user I can read the folder content, but not the files. But when I'm trying to exec the script this is what I get

```
[iron@localhost /]$ ./scripts/macchange 
/bin/bash: ./scripts/macchange: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? If I give my user permission to read it suddenly works.

Explanation why it's different then the possible duplicate: I didn't realize bash needs to read the file to execute it. I thought it's an issue of folder to file permissions.

Comment: How is it going to execute it, if it can't read it?

Comment: What's the purpose of 1 in chmod then? I thought that's the whole idea. User cannot read the information, but can execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/bash` will not be allowed to read the contents of the file to execute.

You will **have** to enable read permissions.

```
chmod 751 /scripts/macchange ##If you only want the user's of the same group to access the file.
```

Comment: So then the user can read the content of the file right?

Comment: Yes. the user will be able to read the content.

Comment: Damn. Ok I'll have to look for another solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @alex3wielki Look at this answer. Might help solve your question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77538/237568

Comment: That should solve it.