# How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?

Tags: sudo

I need to run something as sudo without a password, so I used `visudo` and added this to my `sudoers` file:

```
MYUSERNAME ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program
```

Then I tried it out:

```
$ sudo /path/to/my/program
[sudo] password for MYUSERNAME:
```

Why does it ask for a password? How can I run/use commands as root with a non-root user, without asking for a password?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You have another entry in the [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html) file, typically located at `/etc/sudoers`, which also matches your user. The `NOPASSWD` rule needs to be after that one in order for it to take precedence.

Having done that, `sudo` will prompt for a password normally for all commands except `/path/to/my/program`, which it will always let you run without asking for your password.

Comment: would this still work if the `/path/to/my/program` was a python script?

Comment: Can the *program* instead be an alias, set for bash (ie in `.bashrc`)? Or even a shell script inside `/usr/local/sbin`? To try out.

Comment: Nikos - no it cannot be an alias. It must point to a real path.

Comment: sudoers? where is? heawy to use your answer (

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov: It's usually in `/etc`, but some systems put it elsewhere. If you can't find it, try `man sudoers`. The local location for that file should be substituted into the `man` page at the time `sudo` was built for that system.

Comment: @WarrenYoung i mean `$ sudo visudo` - usefull. `entry in the sudoers`
UFO for me

Answer (score 194):

If there are multiple matching entries in `/etc/sudoers`, sudo uses the last one. Therefore, if you can execute any command with a password prompt, and you want to be able to execute a particular command without a password prompt, you need the exception last.

```
myusername ALL = (ALL) ALL
myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program
```

Note the use of `(root)`, to allow the program to be run as root but not as other users. (Don't give more permissions than the minimum required unless you've thought out the implications.)

*Note for readers who aren't running Ubuntu or who have changed the default sudo configuration (Ubuntu's sudo is ok by default)*: Running shell scripts with elevated privileges is risky, you need to start from a clean environment (once the shell has started, it's too late (see [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)), so you need sudo to take care of that). Make sure that you have `Defaults env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers` or that this option is the compile-time default (`sudo sudo -V | grep env` should include `Reset the environment to a default set of variables`).

Comment: ex to go root from jhon with sudo su an no pass ----->  



john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su

Comment: @adrian If you want to allow arbitrary commands as root, make that `john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: all`. There's no point in going via `su`.

Comment: Question: should I alter the permissions of my shell script so that it can get modified and read by root user only, for security? I'm thinking about an attacker modifying the script, which has all the permissions granted without the need of a password, so that it does what he/she wants. Obviously, the attacker can't even read sudoers file to know which scripts have this privilege, but can still try with all my custom scripts once he/she finds the folder in which they are stored in hope some are allowed, or something like that.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski If you have a sudo rule that runs the script (directly or indirectly) then it's vital that only root (or people who have root privileges anyway) can write to the script file, and to the directory containing the script file, and to its parent directory and so on. It doesn't matter that anyone can read the script file (unless it contains a password or something, but that's a bad idea, if there's a password it should be in its own file, otherwise there's too much risk of accidentally leaking it e.g. by copy-pasting that section of the code in a question on this site).

Comment: Much better than accepted answer

Comment: Do we have to reboot after making changes into the `/etc/sudoers` file? @Gilles

Comment: @alper No. Very few things require rebooting. After changing `sudoers`, you don't need to do anything special: `sudo` checks it each time.

Answer (score 28):

### **WARNING**: This answer has been deemed insecure. See comments below

**Complete Solution:** The following steps will help you achieve the desired output:

1. Create a new script file (replace `create_dir.sh` with your desired script name):

   ```
   vim ~/create_dir.sh
   ```

   The script will be created in the user’s home directory
2. Add some commands that only a `root` or `sudo` user can execute like creating a folder at the root directory level:

   ```
   mkdir /abc
   ```

   **Note:** Don’t add `sudo` to these commands. Save and exit (using `:wq!`)
3. Assign execute permissions to it using:

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x create_dir.sh
   ```
4. Make changes so that this script doesn’t require a password.

   1. Open the `sudoers` file:

      ```
      sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
      ```
   2. Add the following line at the end:

      ```
      ahmad ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/ahmad/create_dir.sh
      ```

      Replace `ahmad` with whatever your username is. Also make sure this is the last line. Save and exit.
5. Now when running the command add `sudo` before it like:

   ```
   sudo ./create_dir.sh
   ```

   This will run the commands inside the script file without asking for a password.

Follow the easy steps mentioned here http://step4wd.com/2013/09/14/run-root-commands-in-linux-ubuntu-without-password/

Comment: It would be better if you provided the relevant steps here and used the link as a backup for more detailed information. That way your answer retains possible value even if that link would not be valid anymore.

Comment: This advice is insecure. The `sudo` part of `sudo chmod u+x create_dir.sh` is unnecessary as the user has (presumably) ownership over his/her home dir. Since the user can write to `create_dir.sh`, you have effectively given a free root shell to that user.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Which means also to any program running as the user. Might as well just allow the user to run anything with sudo without a password.

Comment: Am I missing something? I believe that the entire `chmod` is unnecessary, since you’re relying on `sudo` to elevate your privileges.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to avoid having to use sudo nor have to change the sudoers config file, you can use:

```
sudo chown root:root path/to/command/COMMAND_NAME
sudo chmod 4775 path/to/command/COMMAND_NAME
```

This will make the command run as root without the need of sudo.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of this solution before, mind boggling

Comment: @RyanNerd:  This is not a secure solution.  Not only can the OP now run the command as root without a password, buy anybody can now run the command as the root user.

Comment: "chmod 4775 filename" is one way. Second, maybe better way to [SETUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_an_executable_file), without re-defining whole file permissions is "chmod u+s filename"

Comment: sudo chmod 005 is safe. You don't wanna give writing permissions to the current user. Otherwise anyone in your session could do anything with your script.

Answer (score 13):

I think your syntax is wrong. At least I use the following which works for me:

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable
```

Comment: The `(ALL)` part is optional, leaving it out has exactly the same effect. Having `(root)` would be better though, but its absence doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: +1 for sudo for this command and nothing else! No reason to break the entire system...

Comment: @Johan: That was already in the question.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an distro like Manjaro, you must deal first with a file that overrides the definition of `/etc/sudoers`; you may delete it or work directly with that file to add your new configurations.

This file is:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/10-installer
```

*The ONLY way to see it is under root privileges; you cannot list this directory without it. This file is Manjaro specific: you may find this configuration with a different name, but in same directory.*

In your file of choice, you can add the following line(s) to get your desired configuration(s):

Ignore authentication for a group:

```
%group ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or Ignore authentication for a user:

```
youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or Ignore authentication on a specific executable for a user:

```
youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable
```

**QUICK NOTE: You are opening a door to use `sudo` without authentication, which means you can run everything modifying everything on your system; use it with responsibility.**

Answer (score 4):

Verify that sudo is not aliased. Run like this

```
/usr/bin/sudo /path/to/my/program
```

For example a shell alias like this one:

```
alias sudo="sudo env PATH=$PATH"
```

may cause this behaviour.

Comment: You are right, my comment was out of order *here*, sorry for that. Nevertheless I'm intrigued - how do you expect aliasing to change the processing of `sudoers` by sudo. Or are you talking about redirecting `sudo` to something that always prints this error message to scoop passwords? That is unlikely the case here...

Comment: I was having the same problem as the OP. It turned out to be caused by having `alias sudo="sudo env PATH=$PATH"` in my `~/.bashrc`. Rather than just solving it for myself and blindly just going about my business, I submitted my answer as a possible solution for anyone else that comes along this thread.

Comment: That's fine, but when it is not obvious (which in this case isn't at least to some people) it is good to put an explanation into the answer to provide some context and prevent people from blindly using magic incantations. +2 (-(-1) + +1). :)

Answer (score 3):

In the script `sudoers` which is inside /etc/ uncomment the line given below:

`#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`

Create one file with any name inside /etc/sudoers.d/ directory and add the content as given in the maximum answers.
Like for all users as root

```
#!/bin/bash
ALL    ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/of/the/script/which/you/want/to/run/as/root
```

This is the safest way to run the script with root permission.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute your script you need to run it as `sudo /path/to/my/script`.

**Edit:** Based on your comment to another answer, you want to run this from an icon. You will need to create a `.desktop` file that executes your program with sudo, just like on the terminal.

You could also consider using `gtk-sudo` for a visual password prompt.

You should probably consider the idea that you shouldn't be running things as root and that changing the system farther down the road so that you don't need root permissions at all would be a better way to go.

Comment: **Do not make shell scripts setuid**. See [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts).

Comment: I considered not even mentioning it because it's such a bad option. I just deleted it because I'm worried this asker might use the advice even with the warning that it was bad advice!

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me (also tried some of the other answers, that might have helped):

The script I was calling was in `/usr/bin`, a directory that I don't have write permissions to (though I can usually read any files there). The script was chmodded +x (executable permisison), but it still didn't work. Moving this file to a path in my home directory, instead of `/usr/bin`, I was finally able to call it with sudo without entering a password.

Also something I doubted about (clarifying for future readers): You need to run your script as sudo. Type `sudo` when *calling* the script. Don't use `sudo` for the command inside your script that actually needs root (changing keyboard backlight in my case). Perhaps that also works, but you don't need to, and it seems like a better solution not to.

Comment: The second paragraph had the answer to my problem

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar Glad it helped!

Comment: Actually using `sudo` inside of a script is perfectly fine provided you have the appropriate rights (set in `sudoers`) to run the command in question without a password. It makes things a bit more secure.

Comment: could really use this answer re-written as a step-by-step 'this is how you do it' rather than as a dialogue with the other answers

Comment: @WalrustheCat Good point. Re-reading my answer, I think I might have been confused a little myself. Right now though, I don't remember what the exact situation was so I can't really do a better writeup. If you figure it out, perhaps a combination of several answers, by all means submit a new answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility might be to install, configure, then use the [super](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/super/) command to run your script as

```
super /path/to/your/script
```

---

If you want to run some binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (e.g. that you have compiled into [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary from some C source code) -which is *not* a script- as root, you might **consider making it [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)** (and actually `/bin/login`, `/usr/bin/sudo` and `/bin/su` and `super` are all using that technique). However, be very careful, **you could open a huge security hole**.

Concretely, your program should be paranoically coded (so check all arguments and the environment and outside conditions before "acting", assuming a potentially hostile user), then you could use [seteuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) and friends (see also [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)) carefully (see also [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) & [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)...)

You'll use `chmod u+s` (read [chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)) when installing such a binary.

But **be very careful**.

Read many things about *setuid*, including [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), before coding such a thing.

Notice that a script, or any [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))-ed thing, cannot be setuid. But you could code (in C) a small setuid-binary wrapping it.

Be aware that on Linux, application code interact with the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) using [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Most of them could fail, see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). A lot of Linux applications (e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [GNU gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/)) are open source : you are allowed to download then study and contribute to their source code.

Comment: Advanced Linux Programming is a dead link.

Answer (score 1):

To allow any user to execute program as sudo without asking password you can add following line

`%sudo   ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/program`

in `/etc/sudoers`

Note that **%sudo** make it.

Comment: While that's one way to accomplish a sudo rule, it doesn't answer the question about why setting the NOPASSWD flag on this rule still resulted in a password prompt. See the accepted answer for an idea why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you can use python [pudo](https://pypi.org/project/pudo/1.0.0/) package.

Installation:

```
user$ sudo -H pip3 install pudo # you can install using pip2 also
```

Below is the code snippet for using in python automation for running commands under root privilege:

```
user$ python3 # or python2
>>> import pudo
>>> (ret, out) = pudo.run(('ls', '/root')) # or pudo.run('ls /root')
>>> print(ret)
>>> 0
>>> print(out)
>>> b'Desktop\nDownloads\nPictures\nMusic\n'
```

Below is the cmd example for running commands under root privilege:

```
user$ pudo ls /root
Desktop  Downloads  Pictures  Music
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you are customizing what commands can be run via `sudo` you should be making these changes in a separate file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of editing the `sudoers` file directly. You should also always use `visudo` to edit the file(s). You should NEVER grant `NOPASSWD` on `ALL` commands.

Example:
`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/mynotriskycommand`

Insert your line granting permission:
`myuser ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/program`

Then save and exit and `visudo` will warn you if you have any syntax errors.

You can run `sudo -l` to see the permissions that your user has been granted, if any of the user specific `NOPASSWD` commands appear BEFORE any `%groupyouarein ALL=(ALL) ALL` command in the output you will be prompted for your password.

If you find yourself creating lots of these sudoers.d files then perhaps you will want to create them named per user so they are easier to visualize. Keep in mind that the ordering of the FILE NAMES and of the RULES within the file is very important, the LAST one loaded wins, whether it is MORE or LESS permissive than the previous entries.

> You can control the file name ordering by using a prefix of 00-99 or aa/bb/cc, though also keep in mind that if you have ANY files that don't have numeric prefix, they will load after the numbered files, overriding the settings. This is because depending on your language settings the "lexical sorting" the shell uses sorts numbers first and then may interleave upper and lowercase when sorting in "ascending" order.

Try running `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | sort` and `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | LANG=C sort` to see whether your current language prints `AaBbCc` etc or `ABC` then `abc` to determine what the best "last" letter prefix to use would be.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for the case where you want to **run a command without password only if it has a specific set of options, where a part of the options is variable**. AFAIK it is not possible to use variables or value ranges in sudoers declarations, i.e. you can allow access explicitly to `command option1` but not `command option2` using:

`user_name    ALL=(root) /usr/bin/command option1`

but if the structure is `command option1 value1`, where `value1` can vary, you would need to have explicit sudoers lines for each possible value of `value1`. Shell script provides a way around it.

This answer was inspired by M. Ahmad Zafar's answer and fixes the security issue there.

1. Create a shell script where you call the command without `sudo`.
2. Save the script in a root-privileged folder (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/`), make the file root-owned (e.g. `chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/script_name`) with no write access for others (e.g. `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/script_name`).
3. Add the exception to sudoers using visudo:

   `user_name    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/script_name`.
4. Run your script `sudo script_name`.

For example, I want to change display sleep timeout on macOS. This is done using:

`sudo pmset displaysleep time_in_minutes`

I consider changing the sleep timeout an innocent action that doesn't justify the hassle of password typing, but `pmset` can do many things and I'd like to keep these other things behind the sudo password.

So I have the following script at `/usr/local/bin/ds`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'To set displaysleep time, run "sudo ds [sleep_time_in_minutes]"'
else
        if [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)$ ]]; then
                pmset displaysleep $1 
        else
                echo 'Time must be 0..180, where 0 = never, 1..180 = number of minutes'
        fi
fi
```

At the end of `sudoers` file I have the following line:

`user_name    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/ds`

To set the timeout at 3 minutes, I run my script from the ordinary user account `user_name`:

`sudo ds 3`

PS Most of my script is input validation, which is not mandatory, so the following would also work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
pmset displaysleep $1
```