# Set GPIO permissions cleanly

Tags: linux, permissions, embedded, arm, gpio

Can the default permissions and ownership of /sys/class/gpio/ files be set, e.g. by configuring udev? The point would be to have a real gid for processes that can access GPIO pins on a board.

Most "solutions" include suid wrappers, [scripts with chown](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8999&p=105567) and trusted middleman binaries. Web searches turn up [failed attempts to write udev rules](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=9667&p=111315).

(related: [Q1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18967/run-python-portio-script-as-normal-user-without-root-access))

(resources: [avrfreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation:Linux/GPIO), [linux](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/gpio.txt;h=36af58eba136bac198ea3b1f33f34236be9ce5df;hb=HEAD), [udev](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPIO interface seems to be built for system (uid root) use only and doesn't have the features a /dev interface would for user processes. This includes creation permissions.

In order to allow user processes (including daemons and other system services) access, the permissions need to be granted by a root process at some point. It could be an init script, a middleman, or a manual (sudo) command.

Answer (score 4):

I added the /etc/udev/rules.d/99-gpio.rules to set all permission correctly and cleanly:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport'"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/chown root:gpio /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/edge /sys%p/direction /sys%p/value", RUN+="/bin/chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/edge /sys%p/direction /sys%p/value"
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu run.

```
sudo apt install rpi.gpio-common
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems to also be in Debian and contain udev rules: https://packages.debian.org/buster/rpi.gpio-common

Answer (score 2):

I use this (assuming gpio group already created):

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-gpio.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", GROUP:="gpio", MODE:="0660"

Comment: This post, [GPIO permissions for libgpiod sudo or not](https://www.udoo.org/forum/threads/gpio-permissions-for-libgpiod-sudo-or-not.32453/) has something similar using this rule, `SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip[0-4]", GROUP="gpiod", MODE="0660"`