# How do you get NOPASSWD sudo option to work in Fedora 15?

Tags: fedora, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

I installed fedora 15. I use `sudo visudo` to modify sudoers file and add the following line:

```
USERNAME  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I then logout and login. I try doing any sudo command like `sudo gvim &`... but I am still getting prompted for password.

**How do you get NOPASSWD sudo option to work in Fedora 15?**

- Is my syntax wrong?
- Is there some Fedora 15 thing that is preventing this to work?

---

UPDATE:

After seeing answers below talking about "the order of your sudoers file" I decided to copy the full sudoers file in here. I took the liberty of removing most white space lines, all comments lines, and all lines containing the string "Default":

```
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
USERNAME    ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL,/bin/mount,/bin/umount

%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Comment: I am a little frustrated... because this is supposed to be soo simple.

Comment: Could this be of help? http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/138695-solved-nopasswd-etc-sudoers.html (look at the end for the solution)

Comment: wow nico. i went there. and you are correct. the problem was in the ordering of the statements in the sudoers file! If you had posted a full answer I would have given you the upvote/accepted answer.

Comment: I did not know if that was actually the issue and I never used NOPASSWD before... so I just posted it as a comment. At the end, what's important is that you solved the problem :)

Comment: The problem is not related to sudo but to how does fedora intregrates sudo...which is with PAM. You may have the good config lines in the good order in your sudo config, it will not be sufficient on a fedora host: you will have to tune the PAM config for sudo by editing /etc/pam.d/su and add a line like "auth  sufficient pam_admin.so trust use_uid" assuming you configured a NOPASSWD sudo config for group admin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Often this is caused by the order of statements in `/etc/sudoers`, make sure that you have any permissions that may override it *before* you declare `NOPASSWD`, or it may be overridden by a later command.

Bear in mind that you should not be using `sudo` with `gvim` anyway -- graphical programs should be run with `gksu`, `kdesu`, or an alternative, otherwise you risk problems (particularly notable are problems with `~/.ICEauthority` and other often-essential files).

Comment: FYI, if you read my post it says " I use `sudo visudo` to modify sudoers file".

Comment: Chris and @nico, both of you are correct. The problem was in the ordering of the sudoers file.

Comment: I don't understand, what relevance does using `visudo` have in the context of my answer?

Comment: oh my bad. I had selective hearing... when I read your answer I thought it said 'you should not be editing the sudoers file with gvim'. When in reality you are saying "if you need to call a graphical program like gvim you can't use 'sudo'".

Comment: the solution was to move my NOPASSWD line so that it came AFTER the "%wheel" line!

Comment: Please correct me but. The original ordering makes it so that my NOPASSWD line is overrided by the "%wheel" line which forces you to always enter a password, correct?

Comment: What is the difference between: `USERNAME    ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL` and `USERNAME    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:ALL`