# shell script  to execute in root mode

Tags: shell, root

I need execute script that have commands which should be run in root mode.
If I put `sudo` before command then when I run script I see permission denied ( I don't have a chance to write password).
If I run script with sudo then it writes - command not found.
If I put `sudo su` in the beginning of the script then after I inter password nothing happens. Script executes only when exit root mode.
How can make such script? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a script to not require a password via sudo with e.g. the following in  `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: @:jmtd I did not but it on sudo myscript it still ask password

Comment: @user16610 See [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830) : the more specific rule needs to come after the more general rule.

Answer (score 3):

(Posted as a new answer since I can't comment & the edit is too small)

You can end the command with `""` to prevent the user from running the command with arbitrary arguments.

```
user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script ""
```

Now `sudo /path/to/your/script` works but `sudo /path/to/your/script foo bar` fails.