# How to run sudo commands remotely via ssh -t?

Tags: ssh, shell-script, sudo

I have a script that logs into a remote host via `ssh -t` and uses `sudo service foo restart`.

The requirement is to avoid the prompt for a password on the remote host. The remote host authenticates via SSH certificate. The `sudoers` file on the remote host allows that user to execute the service command with `NOPASSWD`.

However, during my tests, I'm prompted for a password and this is unacceptable. If I run this manually without the `-t` flag, it works. However the `-t` flag throws everything off.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do the authentication logs say? Typically `auth.log` or `secure` in `/var/log`.

Comment: Are you sure that `NOPASSWD` is set? Remember that [only the last match in `sudoers` counts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt). Also remember that if `sudo` doesn't prompt you for a password, it can be because of the cache, so make sure to flush it before each test with `sudo -k`.

Comment: What is the contents of the `NOPASSWD` line? Why is `-t` needed? Another option is to create a key for just that command, going directly to root , and use the `command=""` parameter in the `authorized_keys` file. (passswordless SSH keys allowing for a full root login can be a huge security risk...)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe disabling the `requiretty` option in `sudoers` and running `ssh` *without* the `-t` flag (or with `-T`) works.

Add something like this to `sudoers` (untested):

```
Defaults:{your ssh user} !requiretty
```

Combine that with the `NOPASSWD` you're already using and you should be able to run the sudo command without a pseudo-tty allocated.

You could also change `requiretty` for the command instead of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an SSH key and transfer it to the remote host.

1. Use the following command to generate an RSA SSH key

   ```
   [root@localhost ~] ssh-keygen

   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):  Hit ENTER
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): Hit ENTER
   Enter same passphrase again: Hit ENTER
   ```
2. Find `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and transfer that key to remote using the following command:

   ```
   ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remote:/root
   ```

Now try to login; it won't ask for your remote password.

Comment: We already have the ssh keys in their proper place. That part works. There's something about how ssh -t created a pseudotty that is affecting my ability to execute sudo commands where the user has NOPASSWD enabled. What's happening is that this script logs into a server, parses a list of severs that are our middleware servers, then does a ssh -t "sudo service middleware restart" operation via shell script. The problem is that when the script iterates through the list, user is prompted for password despite NOPASSWD set in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked fine like this, but with notice about: 
*Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal*

```
ssh -t username@hostname1 << 'EOS'
sudo sh
hostname
EOS

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
hostname1
```

Comment: But you need key pair for it, if key pair with passphrase, you can use keychain