# Using setuid Properly

Tags: osx, setuid

I've been scared too much by the warning about setuid. However I cannot find a way around using it.

I want to be able to run:
`arp -s 198.51.100.1 00:53:00:12:34:56`
as the user `steven` but arp -s requires root.

Would this be the correct way to do it?

```
sudo nano example.sh
sudo chmod u+s example.sh
sudo chmod og-w example.sh
sudo chmod o+x example.sh
./example.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short story: don't use setuid shell scripts (or *any* setuid/setgid script).

Long story: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts/2910#2910)

Solution: invoke the command using `sudo`.

```
sudo arp -s 198.51.100.1 00:53:00:12:34:56
```

To allow the user `steven` to run this command without entering a password, run `visudo` and add the following line:

```
steven ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: arp -s 198.51.100.1 00\:53\:00\:12\:34\:56
```

If you have other sudo entries for `steven`, [the `NOPASSWD:` one(s) need to come last](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).

Comment: Could I used `nano` instead?

Comment: @Steven Always use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file. It verifies the syntax. Despite the name, it doesn't necessarily invoke `vi`; set the environment variable `VISUAL` to your favorite editor, e.g. `export VISUAL=nano`.

Comment: I kept getting syntax errors. `steven ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/arp` works however

Comment: @Steven Ah, my bad, `:` needs escaping in the command. Edited.