# Passwordless sudo not working

Tags: sudo

I am trying to setup my server so that I can restart Apache as `userx` without having to enter a `sudo` password.  However when I logon as `userx` and run `sudo /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart` it asks me for a password.  What have I got wrong?

Below is the content of my `sudoers` file.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification
userx ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Let me add back in my edit where I point out what the answer was and explain where I found the solution in case other people stubmle across this.

Turns out that userx was a member of the admin group and the %admin group entry was overwriting the settings. Moving the userx line below the %admin line solved the problem.

This answer also helped [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

Comment: Try putting `/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart` within double quotes

Comment: You should auto-answer your question with a proper answer and accept it as the correct one. It may help others :-).