# Automating backups run from a bash script in Linux the right way

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, backup

I have a bash script I wrote to backup a Moodle installation.  It works fine, I've tested the backups, but there's a problem with it; when I do the backups, since I have to use `sudo` to type the password every time, I have to physically type in the password instead of just running a `cron` job to do it automatically.

Now I suspect this has something to do with either something I don't know about `cron` or using an SSH key; either way I'd like to automate the backup.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn on Maintance mode and log it...
logger "BEGIN Turning on maintance mode in moodle"
lynx -cmd_script=./backupScripts/turnOnMaintMode http://moodle.leeand00domain.local
logger "END Turning on maintance mode complete."

logger "BEGIN Creating Backup Directory"
export bkdir=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
mkdir $bkdir 
cd $bkdir
logger "END Creating Backup Directory"

#Get a backup copy of the database
logger "BEGIN Backing up the Moodle Database"
mysqldump -u moodleuser --password=XXXXX -C -Q -e --create-options moodle > moodle-database.sql
logger "END Backing up the Moodle Database"

#Get a backup copy of moodle data 
logger "BEGIN Backing up moodledata"
tar -cvzf moodledata.tar.gz --exclude='/var/moodledata/cache' --exclude='/var/moodledata/lang' --exclude='/var/moodledata/sessions' --exclude='/var/moodledata/temp' /var/moodledata  && tar -cvzf moodleinstallation.tar.gz /var/www
logger "END Backing up moodledata"

cd ..

tar -cvzf  $bkdir.tar.gz  $bkdir

# Turn off Maintance mode and log it...
logger "BEGIN Turning off maintance mode in moodle"
lynx -cmd_script=./backupScripts/turnOffMaintMode http://moodle.leeand00domain.local
logger "END Turning off maintance mode in moodle complete."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do 1 of the following things.

#### Method #1 - system crons

Add the backup script to the system's crons rather then to a actual user's crontab entry. Most systems maintain a directory structure under `/etc` like this:

```
$ ls -1d /etc/cron.*
/etc/cron.d
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.deny
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
```

You can simply place a script you want to run at whatever frequency in the appropriate directory.

#### Method #2 - password less sudo

The other approach would involve setting up a entry in your `/etc/sudoers` file using the command `visudo` to edit it. This entry would grant passwordless access to the user's crontab entry for this particular script. Your entry in their crontab would be something like this:

```
$ sudo ...your script...
```

And the entry in your `/etc/sudoers` file would be something like this:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/cronscript.sh
```

#### References

- [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest getting into the crontab of root using,

```
sudo crontab -e
```

When you include it as the first command in your script, all the commands will be executed as root crontab.

If you need more information look into [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) page.

> Commands that normally run with administrative privileges (i.e. they
>   are generally run using sudo) should be added to the root user's
>   crontab (instead of the user's crontab)