# sudoers conditional/combo command is possible?

Tags: sudo

I want to allow sudo this way:

```
myuser ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/pkill -fx "/usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s" || /usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s
```

so I get only a single running instance of nethogs.

visudo accepts it, but I am unable to run these commands without a password...

Failed attempts:

```
sudo '/usr/bin/pkill -fx "/usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s" || /usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s'
sudo /usr/bin/pkill -fx "/usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s" || sudo /usr/sbin/nethogs -v 3 -s
```

PS.: this version of nethogs is compiled from its cvs on sf.net

Comment: In addition to the answer by n.st, note that the `NOPASSWD:` entry has to come after any entry that would match but require a password. See [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the names or paths of programs or script (and optionally arguments for them) in the `sudoers` file — shell constructs like `||` won't work.
Quoting `man sudoers`:

```
command name ::= file name |
                 file name args |
                 file name '""'
```

The easiest way to work around this will be to create a script that executes your set of commands, make it writeable only by root and grant to permission to execute it via `sudo`.

---

The manpage for `sudo` actually gives an example that executes commands in a subshell, but I haven't found a way to allow that in the `sudoers` configuration <sub>(and neither has [the sudo-users mailing list](http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2009-July/004128.html))</sub>.

Comment: oh.. btw I think the parent folders of such script must also be owned by root for safety; I will try it but I think it will surely work, brb, thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower "only-writeable by root" is not the same thing as "owned by root" and it is the former that matters.

Comment: lets say that to the unadvised it may be tricky, I had a file owned by root at my home folder, and could do nothing to it; but after some tests I found that I could remove it, even if I could not set its ownership again to root, at the execution point of view that ownership was initially useless; we could have some system warning/check concerning this; I mean, not here on your answer, it is just a thought :>