# Call sudo from a script called by xbindkeys

Tags: sudo, xbindkeys

I have a macbook pro and I am in the process of binding scripts to control the backlight level on my keyboard.  I wrote 2 scripts and they work perfectly I just cant get them to run on a keypress.  I have xbindkeys set up and running with a configuration file named .xbindkeysrc in the configuration file I attempt to bind the scripts to my special function keys (same row as fn).  I know my configuration file loads properly because when I run `xbindkeys -s` it shows the two attempted bindings that are not currently working.  Here is the contents of my.xbindkeysrc file

```
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
#
# Version: 0.1.3
#
# If you edit this, do not forget to uncomment any lines that you change.
# The pound(#) symbol may be used anywhere for comments.
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h 
# The XK_ is not needed. 
#
# List of modifier (on my keyboard): 
#   Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock), 
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll). 
#
# Another way to specifie a key is to use 'xev' and set the 
# keycode with c:nnn or the modifier with m:nnn where nnn is 
# the keycode or the state returned by xev 
#
# This file is created by xbindkey_config 
# The structure is : 
# # Remark 
# "command" 
# m:xxx + c:xxx 
# Shift+... 




#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable



"bash /opt/keyLightInc.sh"
    m:0x0 + c:238
    XF86KbdBrightnessUp 

"bash /opt/keyLightDec.sh"
    m:0x0 + c:237
    XF86KbdBrightnessDown 

#
# End of xbindkeys configuration
```

I started it with the verbose option. Here is the output:

```
screen 0 for window 259
Start program with fork+exec call
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Is there an entry in `/etc/sudoers` for those scripts? Why are you calling them with `sudo bash`?

Comment: I thought I needed it because within the script a file is modified with a 0-255 value for the brightness of the keys, to modify this file it must be called by super user.  I just executed the script in xterm without sudo and it worked just fine so I removed it, still no luck.  Edited my original post

Comment: Do the scripts have a shebang? Can you remove the `bash` and just call the script?

Comment: I just added `#!/bin/sh` to the beginning of each file, now when I call the script it says `permission denied` and `sudo` before the script path results in the error `command not found`

Comment: Is it executable? It doesn't sound like it. Also, is `/opt/` in your PATH?

Comment: Made it executable now the script is called no problem with `/opt/keyLightInc.sh` I edited my xbindkeys config file and relaunched xbindkeys.  Still no luck.

Comment: Start it with the verbose option and see what is printed to the temrinal when you hit those keys. [Mine works fine](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/tip/.xbindkeysrc)...

Comment: the output is here `got screen 0 for window 259; Start program with fork+exec call; sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `sudoers` file sets the `requiretty` option, then you can only call sudo from a terminal.

If your `sudoers` file doesn't set the `requiretty` option, then you can call sudo from anywhere, but if it prompts for a password, a terminal is required. The message “sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified” indicates that sudo tried to prompt you for a password, but failed.

You can pass the `-A` option to tell sudo to use a different method to prompt you for a password. Since you're running in X11, you can use the `ssh-askpass` program distributed with OpenSSH, which prompts for a password in an X11 window.

```
sudo -A /usr/bin/ssh-askpass whatever-command-you-need-to-execute-as-root
```

Alternatively, [allow yourself to run this program without entering a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt/13058#13058).

Comment: Exactly the problem, I ended up modifying /etc/sudoers thankyou