# Bash launch certain commands like being a root user without being root user

Tags: bash, privileges

I've the following problem.

When I launch df command being a usual user of machine it outputs what I need:

[image]

But when I try to launch it from another user (www-data in this case) I have problems with permissions:

[image]

I understand that this is because  user www-data doesn't have enough privileges. 
But I don't want to up his privileges.

It would be perfect to allow  this user  to launch only some programs as root without entering the root password without increasing its privileges. 
It's ok if I'll be asked to enter root's password one time and will be able to run command with full privileges without entering root password anymore.

Note:

I have root access to machine.

Can it be reached somehow?

Comment: You already know `sudo`. Maybe you use it for "make me root" only but it is not limited to that. Have a look at `man sudoers`.

Comment: You are looking for `NOPASSWD`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because `www-data` doesn't have enough privileges, it's because `www-data` doesn't own the files question.  Permissions for both locations are likely set to `drwx------`, meaning only the owner can read the file.  `gvfs` is used for a mount point for [Filesystems in Userspace (FUSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) and is therefore owned by a user and `/media/sh/...` is apparently owned by the user `sh`.  Since `/dev/sda4` was mounted to a mount point owned by `sh`, 'www-data' can't traverse it.  Even to a user with elevated privileges the gvfs file system will generally be inaccessible.

For the `/media/sh/...` issue, you could change the permissions for that mount point or simply unmount and re-mount `/dev/sda4` to another mount point that has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions.  For gvfs, you can't traverse it as another user.  There are work arounds but they shouldn't be implemented on a multi-user system.

Comment: it seems you are right to some extent. Launching program as sudo -u www-data df suffers from this problem, but it can be solved by launching it as  sudo -u www-data sudo df

Comment: You seem to misunderstand.  There is no "process in question".  'www-data' simply does not have access, as the question indicated.  The program is being run as 'www-data', not as root.

Comment: @psusi, I've edited to indicate "files" rather than "processes"; however, with regard to the gvfs, the file systems themselves are processes running in userspace

Comment: Sure, but that's neither here nor there.  The issue is that the permissions do not give www-data access; it is not "acting as root via sudo'; `sudo` is being used here to become www-data, not root.

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing.  The point was that no other user can access the gvfs systems other than the owner, even with elevated privileges, though you're right, that's not really relevant in the sentence I put it in; editing to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow anyone to run `df` with `sudo` without needing to know the root password.

See [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) for more information to get that set up.