# Passing root password safely in a shell script

Tags: linux, debian, shell-script, password

I always boot up my GNU/Linux laptop in console mode. But sometimes I need to bring up the GUI mode. it always requires entering the root password. So I wrote the following script "gogui.sh" and put it in `/usr/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mypassword" | sudo service lightdm start
```

It is a really stupid idea, as if someone read the file, can easily see my password.

Is the an alternative to this?

Comment: you have an aversion to entering your password at a sudo prompt? what are your real goals?

Comment: I am just usurious to see a proper/alternative way

Comment: Why not use the `NOPASSWD` syntax detailed in `sudoers(5)` for password-free calls to that service command, or a suitable wrapper?

Comment: Note that in constructions like these, an unprivileged user doing a process list (with e.g. `ps ax`) at just the right time might also see your password. It won't happen in this particular case, as `echo` is a bash builtin command, but the general approach is also dangerous for this reason.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Passing a password to sudo in a script is utterly pointless. Instead, add a sudo rule [adding the particular command you want to run with the `NOPASSWD` tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt). Take care that the command-specific `NOPASSWD` rule must come after any general rule.

```
saeid ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
saeid ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: service lightdm start
```

But this is probably not useful anyway. `lightdm start` starts a login prompt, but you only need that if you want to let other users log in graphically. You don't need it if all you want is to start a GUI session. Instead, call [`startx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/startx) to start a GUI session from your text mode session. This does not require any extra privilege.

You may need to explicitly specify your window manager or desktop environment, as `startx` might not pick up the same default session type that lightdm uses.

```
startx -- gnome-session
```

Comment: Thanks...thats way way way better :P...I use unity, should I still pass to startx the `gnome-seesion` argument?

Comment: I just checked with `startx`, while it does bring up my desktop, but many things are missing like the unity launcher and also I got no sound, if I do the lightdm service everything works fine

Answer (score 8):

There are some options, and one of them is to add the specific command using `visudo` with the NOPASSWD flag:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript

cat /path/to/myscript
#!/bin/bash
service lightdm start
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Just noticed in your comments you mentioning Unity, so it appears you're running Ubuntu.  My original answer was geared toward **SysVinit** systems, but commands like [`telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/telinit.8.html) still exist for compatibility and will work on distros using *Systemd* or *Upstart*.

***SysV way***

```
    telinit 5
```

On modern Systemd systems, [`telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/telinit.8.html) is redirected to [`systemctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/systemctl.1.html).

***Systemd way***

```
    systemctl isolate runlevel5.target
```

*or*

```
    systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

*Original answer:*

On older non-Systemd distros (RHEL/CentOS 6 and older, for example) the easiest way to switch from console mode to GUI is with the [`telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/telinit.8.html) command.  On the RHEL/Centos distros, for example, multi-user text-based mode is run level 3 and the multi-user GUI mode is run level 5.  Switching from console to GUI mode would be done like this:
By default, `telinit` requires root privileges.  To run this as a normal user without a password, you'll need a `sudoers` entry or set the setuid flag set on the telinit executable.  The `sudo` method is the preferred approach as it can be restricted to just your account.

Answer (score 2):

The classical UNIX way is making the script [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid):

```
$ sudo chown root gogui.sh  #not necessary if root is already the owner of the file
$ sudo chmod u+s gogui.sh
```

This will set a special permission bit on the file:

```
$ ls -l gogui.sh
  -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root [omitted] gogui.sh
```

(Notice the letter `s` instead of `x` in the fourth position.)

If you do this, all the times you run the script, it will be run with the privileges of the file's owner, instead of the ones of the user that runs it.

You can now simplify your script `gogui.sh` to contain only

```
/usr/sbin/service lightdm start
```

Notice that I have added an explicit path for the executable (that I have located by typing `which service`): this is necessary in setuid files, because otherwise the first program called `service` found in your `PATH` will be executed. Forgetting the explicit path would be a **huge** security problem, since it means that any user can tweak the `PATH` variable and run a program of their choice with root privileges.

If you wish, you can also restrict other users from running the files with `chgrp some_group gogui.sh; chmod o-x gogui.sh`, which will make the file executable only for members of `some_group`.

Comment: +1 for suid, tough I think some Linux versions will ignore suid for plaintext scripts for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Since you're specifically referring to `sudo`, stick to [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240358/863). However, since your question title merely was about getting a password to a program's `stdin` and I had a similar situation recently:

```
echo $(read -sp "Password: " password; echo $password) | yourcommand
```

I'll probably earn some bashing for that, but it worked.

Speaking of `bash`, there you can probably also use

```
yourcommand <$(read -sp "Password: " password; echo $password)
```

Comment: This will, however briefly, run a process on your system with the password as a command line argument. This makes it discoverable to other processes. Don't do this.

Comment: @Caleb oh, that's the very thing I wanted to avoid this way m-/ so bash won't redirect e.g. `/dev/fd0` or whatever device `<$(...)` uses without mentioning the password? Or is it due to `read | echo` which can hopefully be solved more elegantly anyway?

Comment: Any time you pass a variable as an argument to a shell command the shell does the expansion from variable name to value. The command that gets executed has the value as the argument and anything with access to the process list can read those arguments. Try for example `var=131 ; sleep $var & ; ps waux | grep 131`. You are passing it to the final command through stdin which is okay but that's only after invoking a builtin shell command with the sensitive data as a regular argument in plain sight.

Comment: @Caleb So the `$password` part is the culprit? One could of course write a small Python script, but I wonder if bash can't handle this on its own...