# pkill in a script

Tags: shell-script, sudo, kill

I am trying to kill a process by his name in a script.

Process :

```
toto 15408     1  0 Nov13 ?        00:20:36 java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /local/toto//conf/:/local/toto//lib/* com.toto.main.entry.Launchtoto processToto
```

in my script :

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u toto /usr/bin/pkill -9 -f $pname
```

In sudoers :

```
script_user server1=(toto) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pkill -9 -f java *
```

It doesn't work. Either I have a sudo error (`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`) or a pkill error (`/usr/bin/pkill: invalid option -- 'X'`).

`pname` contains:

```
java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /local/toto//conf/:/local/toto//lib/* com.toto.main.entry.Launchtoto processToto
```

Comment: What's `pname` set to?  Please add the exact command you're running and the exact output to your question.  To get the command being run, put `set -x` in the line about `pkill` in your script.

Comment: pname contains : java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /local/toto//conf/:/local/toto//lib/* com.toto.main.entry.Launchtoto processToto

Comment: it sounds like sudo disagrees with your intention to have NOPASSWD; are you sure that the username and servernames line up with your sudoers config?

Answer (score 1):

[You used a variable substitution outside of double quotes. Don't do this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) Because `$pname` is unquoted, its value is split at whitespace characters, so `pkill` gets the arguments `-9`, `-f`, `java`, `-Xmx512m`, `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`, `-cp`, `/local/toto//conf/:/local/toto//lib/*`, `com.toto.main.entry.Launchtoto`, `processToto`. Naturally `pkill` complains when it reaches the option `-X` which it doesn't understand.

Just pass the value of `pname` as an argument to `pkill`, i.e.

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u toto /usr/bin/pkill -9 -f "$pname"
```

As for the sudo password prompt, my crystal ball tells me you put the `NOPASSWD` entry before another entry without `NOPASSWD` for the same user. The `NOPASSWD` entry needs to come last. See [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)