# Execute command as a restricted group without entering password

Tags: users

I want to prevent some apps from going to network, so I've created a no-internet group:
    `sudo groupadd -g 9876 no-internet`
and created a script 
`sudo gedit /usr/bin/ni`

```
#!/bin/bash
sg no-internet "$1"
```

And added an iptable rule

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP
```

Now `ni my_command` should run an app in a restricted mode. However, I am getting `sg: failed to crypt password with previous salt: Invalid argument`

How can I run an app as 'no-internet group`, without limiting my own access to LAN/WAN?

I've checked this question (claiming that requirements are contradictory)
[How to switch a group without asking for a password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244727/how-to-switch-a-group-without-asking-for-a-password)

But is it really so?

Comment: is user using `ni` in `no-internet` group ?

Comment: I am a user (admin with root rights). I want to run `ni untrusted-app` in order to prevent this app from talking to internet. I don't want to block my own access to internet though.

Answer (score 2):

user running `sg` command must be the group being sued uppon.

here I belong to `www-data` group

```
archemar@unix:~$ id
uid=1003(archemar) gid=1002(stackexchange) groups=1002(stackexchange),27(sudo),33(www-data)
```

`sg` goes OK

```
archemar@unix:~$ sg www-data id
uid=1003(archemar) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),27(sudo),1002(stackexchange)
```

my gid is `www-data`

Now, I don't belong to `ntp` group

```
archemar@unix:~$ sg ntp id
Password:
sg: failed to crypt password with previous salt: Invalid argument
```