# Why do I still need to run shutdown as sudo after this?

Tags: sudo, reboot

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3.

By default, running shutdown or other commands like reboot, poweroff requires root privilege.

So I added the following line

> lesaff_b ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot,
>   /sbin/shutdown

to /etc/sudoers. I know it still requires that I run these commands as sudo but it won't ask for password, so I create an alias for each of them.

It worked fine the first time, but then it stopped working, I now need to run these commands as sudo and type my password. I know there are others ways of running these commands without sudo, but why doesn't it work whereas it should, and most importantly, why did it work one time ??

Comment: I typed "alias shutdown='sudo shutdown'" and so on for each of the command. But I deleted the aliases to see if it changes anything and it does not.

Comment: I added those command aliases to ~/.bash_aliases

Comment: Yes exactly, "shutdown is aliased to `sudo shutdown'"

Comment: No it still asks for password :/

Comment: do you happen to have any entries in the sudoers file *after* the given line? sudoers works its way *up* the file, so if you also have a line like "lesaff_b ALL=(ALL) ALL" (for example) that would "catch" the shutdown program, sudo will follow that later rule and dutifully prompt you.

Comment: Side note: `sudo -ll` will list how your config is interpreted.

Comment: Your process for adding the aliases looks correct. I trimmed my comment questions to reduce clutter. I think the reason it worked without asking for a password one time only was that your sudo credentials were cached after you used sudo to edit the /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No this is the only line I added to sudoers.
UlrichSchwarz The output properly lists shutdown, reboot and poweroff in sudoers entry.
MarkPlotnick You're probably right, I didn't think about it.

Comment: If Mark is right, then your nopasswd flag is not being used...

Comment: Apparently, but why is that so...?

Comment: Ulrich's suggestion of `sudo -ll` would be helpful to see

Comment: sudo -ll gives me [this output](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/04/1454273820-screenshot-from-2016-01-31-21-53-02.png)

Comment: The last paragraph of that sudo -ll output clearly shows that you have an all:all entry in there somewhere (and notice the lack of !authenticate)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13058/117549 and if you don't see the offending sudo rule, consider pasting it here for someone to review. (Edit it into your Q)

Comment: Thank you that helped me to understand the problem. So yes there are all:all entries, but these were here by default, I didn't added them, so I didn't think these lines could be the cause of the problem, moreover, I didn't have that problem when I was running Ubuntu. So I moved the line with the nopasswd flag after these lines and now it seems to work fine :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the information we learned in the comments, it appears that:

1. you ran some command with `sudo` (perhaps to edit sudoers to add the quoted NOPASSWD line in the Q)
2. sudo cached those credentials, allowing you to run a reboot or shutdown within `timestamp_timeout` (5 minutes by default, I believe)
3. but after the reboot (more than `timestamp_timeout`), you were again prompted for a password for those commands because there was a pre-existing ALL:ALL sudo rule *without* the NOPASSWD flag -- that you didn't add but were caught up in. Because [sudo uses the last matching rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt/13058#13058), it prompted you unexpectedly.

The solution here is to move your rule below the pre-existing ALL:ALL rule (or, if you like, add the NOPASSWD flag to the existing ALL:ALL rule).