# how to do administrative commands without sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo

Is there a possibility to grant administrative privileges to the current logged in user forever?

So I don't have to type `sudo` everytime I want to do something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Answer (score 1):

If `/etc/sudoers` allows your user to run ANY command as root (and not just a limited pre-defined set of commands) then you can run `sudo -i` to get a root login shell.  You'll be able to run commands as root until you `exit` that shell, without having to preface every command with `sudo`.

e.g.

```
$ sudo -i
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# command-requiring-root
# another-command-requiring-root
# yet-another
# and-one-more
# exit
$ id
uid=1000(cas) gid=1000(cas) groups=1000(cas),[...]
```

BTW, if you have a default PS1 (or one containing `\$`) then your prompt will change from `$` to `#` when you are root.

Alternatively, you can use `sudo -s` to get a non-login root shell.  The difference is that a login shell sets the environment (and sources `/root/.bash_profile` etc) as if root had logged in.  A non-login root shell just runs your shell as root, with the environment modified/restricted by `sudo` as for any other command.

Comment: btw, yet another alternative is to  configure `sshd` to allow root logins for authorised keys only (e.g. via `PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and by adding your user's PUBLIC ssh key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`).  Then you can login as root with `ssh root@localhost`.  But there's no advantage of doing this over just using `sudo -i` except that it doesn't require `sudo` to be configured to allow your user to run any command as root...although it does require initial root access (e.g. via `su` and the root password - which is yet another way of getting a root sh).

Comment: Is there a possibility to have administrative privileges forever?

Comment: Yes, by logging in as root and not bothering to have or use a normal user account.  But don't do that, it's a dangerously bad idea and you will one day regret it.  Use root for admin tasks only, and your normal user account (or accounts) for everything else.