# Security ramification of using this line in visudo: yourUSERname ALL=(otherUSERaccount) NOPASSWD: ALL

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm setting up limited accounts on my arch linux build to run proprietary software such as games or windows binaries. These restricted accounts won't have read/write access in my personal folders or any other areas in my OS that I've deemed sensitive.

I'd be using the following command to run applications as a limited user:

```
bash -c 'xhost +local:steam;sudo -u steam -H steam /home/limited.users/steam'
```

This would of course require that I input my sudo password every time I launch something as a restricted users.

Trying to find a way around having to put that password all the time, I ended up coming across this article that was trying to do the exact same things as I was:

[How to run Spotify and Wine under a separate user account](http://www.bobulous.org.uk/misc/Spotify-Linux-Wine.html)

In a section called *Permit your own user account to launch commands under the wine account*, he suggest to edit visudo and add the following line at the end:

his exmaple:

```
bob ALL=(wine) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

more generically:

```
yourUSERname ALL=(theACCOUNTyourTRYINGrunUNDER) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The prospect of being able to run apps as another user with less privileges than my own account without a PW is harmless to me. That being said, I don't have a very thorough understanding of visudo and I wanted to know if this line will do anything other than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
bob ALL=(wine) NOPASSWD: /home/limited.users/steam
```

the key point is you can replace `ALL` by a comma separated list of command allowed.

Note that if there are other entries for `bob` without `NOPASSWD`, [the rules without `NOPASSWD` may need to come first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).