# Why NOPASSWD in visudo on Linux Mint 18 does not work

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, teamviewer

This is a sudoers file which I have on a **Debian 9** server and it **works**.  `/etc/sudoers` contains:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# the following line I've added for sudo to work on Debian, which by default does not
vlastimil   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# and this line I've added just now, so I could enable / disable teamviewer daemon as I wish
vlastimil   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/teamviewer

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Meaning I can now run e.g. the following without entering password:

```
sudo teamviewer daemon disable
sudo teamviewer daemon enable
```

This, however, is a **non-working** sudoers file on **Linux Mint 18** in a sense, it still asks me for password. `/etc/sudoers` contains:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# this line I've added myself, because I felt it is needed, however user vlastimil has had sudo access all the time, added just now
vlastimil   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# and this line I've added just now, so I could enable / disable teamviewer daemon as I wish, but it does not work
vlastimil   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/teamviewer

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I guess there is some difference between Debian and Mint, which makes the added lines non-working.

I read different answers like on this page:

[How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

But I am not clever from it.

**EDIT1:**

The first answer gives on Linux Mint a strange error:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/teamviewer
 Init...
 *** TeamViewer can not be executed with sudo! ***
 Either use your normal user account without sudo
 or use a the real root account to log in to your desktop (not recommended!).
```

I don't get this either.

---

```
$ which teamviewer
/usr/bin/teamviewer

$ file /usr/bin/teamviewer
/usr/bin/teamviewer: symbolic link to /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer

$ file /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer 
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

$ cat /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
#!/bin/bash

# If you see this message, you probably attempted to start TeamViewer.
# Please open a terminal (Konsole, gnome-terminal, xterm),
# navigate to this folder (type 'cd /path/to/teamviewer' [Enter])
# then execute TeamViewer (type './teamviewer' [Enter])


TV_SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -e "$0")")"
source "$TV_SCRIPT_DIR/tvw_main"

Main "$@"
```

**EDIT2:**

For instance on AskUbuntu, as suggested in comments:

[Why is sudoers NOPASSWD option not working?](https://askubuntu.com/a/100112/436624)

and on many other places, there is a solution where they put the rule **after** admin group rule. I've tried it, even rebooted afterwards, but it's still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working

Comment: @rajaganesh87 duplicates can be sourced only from the same site

Comment: I'm confused by your statement "Meaning I can now run e.g. the following without the use of sudo: `teamviewer daemon disable`" -- directly after your first sudoers example. There's a sudo rule for your user to run (sudo) teamviewer; did you mean to say "Meaning I can now run the following without a *password prompt*"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you for pointing the big-a** error out. Fixed it. I don't really know how I put such non-sense sentence together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# this line I've added myself, because I felt it is needed, however user vlastimil has had sudo access all the time, added just now
vlastimil   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# and this line I've added just now, so I could enable / disable teamviewer daemon as I wish, but it does not work
vlastimil   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/teamviewer
```

That first comment suggests that your user is a member of the `sudo` group, which is how users on Linux Mint get `sudo` access by default. And the `sudo` group's rule comes later:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The *last* matching rule wins. It doesn't matter that `vlastimil` has a `NOPASSWD` rule earlier on when this later rule also applies. The `NOPASSWD` rule should come after this one. That is why using a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` works, because these files are included last of all:

```
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

If you are going to add multiple files to `sudoers.d`, use a numbered filename convention (`XX-somefile`), so that you can order them reliably and ensure proper precedence of rules.

Comment: Great suggestion to use the numbered filename convention to ensure reliable ordering.

Answer (score 0):

One solution on Linux Mint 18.2 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 is creating a separate sudoers file using `visudo`, for example:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/teamviewer
```

and putting the extra line:

```
vlastimil   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/teamviewer
```

into it. It may very well be also the most elegant solution, but that is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1):

It’s the absolute path defined for the `teamviewer` binary.

Why not try the following as the `vlastimil` user

`$ sudo /usr/bin/teamviewer`