# How to reuse sudo for a series of commands in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I have script that opens several terminal windows running `iftop` for observing various ports activities.

Each terminal that opens asks me for the sudo password ... which is a bit of a pain considering that there are 5 terminals overall.

So my question is, how do I type in sudo password once and have all the windows run using that permission rather than typing it in per window?

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE="${USER}@${HOSTNAME}"' iftop (h=help, L=lin/log scales, t=line display mode, T=line totals, p=port display)'
gnome-terminal --title "$TITLE" -e 'sh -c "sudo iftop -P -f \"port 22\""' --hide-menubar --zoom=0.85

TITLE="${USER}@${HOSTNAME}"' iftop (h=help, L=lin/log scales, t=line display mode, T=line totals, p=port display)'
gnome-terminal --title "$TITLE" -e 'sh -c "sudo iftop -P -f \"port 33 or port 44\""' --hide-menubar --zoom=0.85

TITLE="${USER}@${HOSTNAME}"' iftop (h=help, L=lin/log scales, t=line display mode, T=line totals, p=port display)'
gnome-terminal --title "$TITLE" -e 'sh -c "sudo iftop -P -f \"(port 55) or (port 66)\""' --hide-menubar --zoom=0.85
```

I did try running the entire script as `sudo` and that results in all the terminals being opened also being a sudo terminal. What I need is a regular terminal running the `sudo iftop` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `timestamp_type` in `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/*` set to `tty` or `ppid`?  `tty` is the default according to `sudo`'s man page:

> **timestamp_type** - `sudoers` uses per-user time stamp files for
>   credential caching.  The `timestamp_type` option can be used to
>   specify the type of time stamp record used.  It has the following
>   possible values:
>
> `global` A single time stamp record is used for all of a user's
>   login sessions, regardless of the terminal or parent process ID.
>   An additional record is used to serialize password prompts when
>   `sudo` is used multiple times in a pipeline, but this does not affect
>   authentication.
>
> `ppid` A single time stamp record is used for all processes with
>   the same parent process ID (usually the shell).  Commands run from
>   the same shell (or other common parent process) will not require a 
>   password for `timestamp_timeout` minutes (15 by default).  Commands
>   run via sudo with a different parent process ID, for example from a
>   shell script, will be authenticated separately.
>
> `tty` One time stamp record is used for each terminal, which
>   means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately.
>   If no terminal is present, the behavior is the same as ppid.
>   Commands run from the same terminal will not require a password for
>   `timestamp_timeout` minutes (15 by default).
>
> The default value is `tty`.
>
> This setting is only supported by version 1.8.21 or higher.

If it **is** set to `tty` or `ppid`, then that explains why you're being asked for a password every time.  Each `sudo` command you're running is being executed in a separate `gnome-terminal`, and thus a separate tty **AND** a different parent PID.

Looks like `global` is the only setting that will allow what you want.

---

If that doesn't help, what's your `timestamp_timeout` setting?  Is it set to `0`?   The default should be 15 minutes.

Also check the other `timestamp*` settings (`timestampdir`, `timestampowner`).  They could cause this problem if `timestampdir` (the default on my debian sid system is **/run/sudo/ts**) doesn't exist or is not rwX by `timestampowner` (default **root**).

`sudo` will log a descriptive error message via syslog **and** email the administrator (root) if these settings result in an error.

---

One other option is to edit `/etc/sudoers` so that your user can run `iftop` without needing to enter your password.  e.g.

```
yourusernamehere ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iftop
```

See [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) for more details on this.

Comment: It looks like 'yourusernamehere ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iftop' is the only viable solution. I hate to make command exceptions for security reasons ... I will just have to settle with entering the pwd for each spawned terminal ...