# Always run script as root

Tags: permissions, root, privileges, setuid

I want to run a command automatically. The problem is that it may only be run after I logged in and that it requires superuser privileges. I've heard of suid before, so I thought I'd use it for this.

I created a script `/mountDropbox.sh` which only contains the bash shebang and a mount command. Then I ran this command to set the setuid bit:

```
sudo chmod 4755 /mountDropbox.sh
```

However, when I try to run it as a normal user, `mount` complains about not being executed with superuser privileges:

```
$ /mountDropbox.sh 
mount: only root can do that
```

Why does this happen? How can I achieve that this file is always executed with superuser privileges?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel `4.4.0-134-generic`. `/` is an ext4 file system.

```
$ ll /mountDropbox.sh 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 77 Sep  4 17:35 /mountDropbox.sh*
```

Comment: You cannot make scripts suid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) [as per chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46585482#46585482)

Comment: @Thomas See above: wrong dupe.  Too low rep to vote for reopen.

Comment: Hum, I had a duplicate comment, but it seems to have disappeared.  It was: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts