# How to run ip netns exec without password?

Tags: sudo, iproute, network-namespaces

I'm on arch and am using a network namespace `wiredlan` for ethernet, using it for LAN based applications and big downloads. I run commands/apps on the netns as:

```
alias runonlan='sudo ip netns exec wiredlan sudo -u me --' 
runonlan command
```

This works, but I want to be able to run it without having to enter password, to make things easier. But as the `command` part of `runonlan command` varies, I can't figure out what to put in sudoers in order to make it run without prompting for password.

So, I tried editing sudoers, adding (one at a time):

```
me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ip *
me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ip netns
me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ip netns exec wiredlan
me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ip netns exec wiredlan sudo -u me --
```

but it still asks for the password. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Try entering complete command ,me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ip netns exec wiredlan

Comment: Also check sequence of rules in sudoers , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: @Bharat That's what the problem is, I can't put the complete command, as what follows after `runonlan` varies according to what I want to run on the LAN. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Another option is to start an xterm as your normal user in the namespace (which needs a password once), and then you can issue commands on the xterm. I like to have a different background for these, in order to not accidently confuse them with my normal xterms.

Comment: @dirkt Yes, currently I use `runonlan tmux -L wiredlantmux` and have an indicator in the prompt for the namespace.