# VISUDO: passwordless sudo does not work for user

Tags: sudo, manjaro

I've altered my `/etc/sudoers` file with `sudo visudo` as follows (showing only uncommented lines, the entire file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/WyDUnevN)):

```
$ grep -v '^#[^i]' /etc/sudoers/ | grep .
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Basically, I have just uncommented one line, which should disable sudo password entry for all members of the wheel group. My user is part of the wheel group as shown in the output of `groups [username]`:

`sys lp wheel network video optical storage scanner power ruben`

However, it is not working, since I have to enter a password every time I open a new terminal window. I've rebooted a couple of times already.

What am I missing?

EDIT1: `id` command returns:
`uid=1000(ruben) gid=1000(ruben) groups=1000(ruben),3(sys),7(lp),10(wheel),90(network),91(video),93(optical),95(storage),96(scanner),98(power)`

Comment: welcome to U&L, is wheel your **primary** group ? does it came first if you do `id` ?

Comment: (Typo-verification: I assume you ran `groups username` and not `group username`?)

Comment: @JeffSchaller whoops, good point. Thanks.

Comment: I can not duplicate the problem using only modifications to `/etc/sudoers` and groups... I've tried adding a system group and a user group, eliminating the `sudo` group... Which distro are you using? And is SELinux running? Is there a group password set? ... and could you provide the output of `grep wheel /etc/group`

Comment: Do you have another applicable rule in a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`? [Order matters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).

Comment: @Archemar `uid=1000(ruben) gid=1000(ruben) groups=1000(ruben),3(sys),7(lp),10(wheel),90(network),91(video),93(optical),95(storage),96(scanner),98(power)`

I never heard of the term **primary** group. I guess it is "ruben"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller You're right, fixed

Comment: @Gilles I think this is it! /etc/sudoers.d contains a file called "10-installer" containing `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL` which should request a password for all commands for every wheel group user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) pointed out there is a file  `/etc/sudoers.d/10-installer` containing `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

The `10-installer` file is **included** in `/etc/sudoers`,  **after** the change I made. This inclusion overwrites my change to the `/etc/sudoers` file.