# Write a string to the file that only root can access when execute the php file

Tags: sudo

I have a case that require I to write some string to the file that only `root` can do that. I was try some solutions base on this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) but none of them works.

**CASE:**
When user was successfully done, he automatically access `writefile.php` which contain script that can write to the file ( `tes.txt` ) that only `root` have access.

I used `visudo` and added this to my `sudoers` file:

`username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/myprogram/writefile.php` **not works!**

`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/myprogram/writefile.php` **not works!**

**My simple code** in `writefile.php`

```
<?php
echo file_put_contents("tes.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: file_put_contents(tes.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: What if you add user in the groups of file using factl.

Answer (score 1):

After trying several times, and also reading a number of related articles. Finally, I understand, the problem is in the arrangement that I did. Hopefully this can help other users who are new about `sudo` n `visudo`.

**Problems:**

**1. Username**

About `username`, the user I added is a user who has login access through the terminal. Even though the application is accessed through the website. So the user should be `www-data`, looks like:

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myprogram/writefile.php
```

**2. Not use exec or shell_exec**

I forget that `writefile.php` should not be directly accessed through the browser. Having to go through another file ( `index.php` ) and then in the file must use `shell_exec` or `exec` to execute `writefile.php` with the `sudo` command. The structure looks like:

**index.php**

```
<?php
exec("sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/myprogram/writefile.php");
?>
```

**writefile.php**

```
<?php
echo file_put_contents("tes.txt","tes write file");
?>
```

Finally open `tes.txt` and works fine! Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a misunderstanding of how sudo works.  Just putting something in the sudoers file will not cause permissions for files to actually change, the file to be must be run like:  sudo php /var/www/html/myprogram/writefile.php by the "username"..   You might also be encountering SELinux issues as running from a file from that location might be disallowed depending on its setting.