# Delete file using sudo along with password in the same command

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

I am using the below command to delete the file:

```
$ echo <Password> | sudo -S -u <User> rm -f <Filename>
rm: cannot remove ‘<Filename>’: Permission denied
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it this way.

You can write a script, then configure `sudo` (`/etc/sudoers`), to allow your user to `sudo` it without a password.

You could also write a `go` program, and then use `suid`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, or any version of what you are trying to do, but you can use `yes`:

```
$ yes 'password' | sudo -Su USER rm -f FILE
```

What you should do instead is allow `USER` passwordless sudo access by modifying `/etc/sudoers` (use `visudo` where available), and adding that user to the required group.

[How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/237982)

Comment: Don't EVER do this - anyone who runs `ps` at the right time will see your password.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if the "EVER" is necessary though.  I can think of some cases where that wouldn't be an issue.  For example on a testing machine with no network connectivity where your password is something like "password".  Even on my personal laptop if someone is logged in and has the ability to run `ps` I already have bigger issues to worry about than them getting my password.