# How to make archlinux-java set ... not require sudo?

Tags: sudo, kde, java, manjaro, openjdk

I have to bounce between Java 8 and Java 13 for different Minecraft versions to work properly, and doing that requires me to type `sudo archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk` or `sudo archlinux-java set java-13-openjdk` - the problem is I want to turn this into a simple double-clickable script I can put on my desktop, and not have it prompt me for the password.

Is there anything I can chmod or something that makes it such that this command doesn't require `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a safer/more cautious approach not to change the default Java environment system-wide just to run different versions of a single program.

You can, instead, start a program with a modified `PATH` to make it use a specific Java version (as suggested in the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Launching_an_application_with_the_non-default_java_version), where `archlinux-java` is documented):

```
$ PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-<version>-openjdk/bin${PATH:+:$PATH}" your_program
```

If you use a `.desktop` file to launch your program, edit its [`Exec` key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html):

```
Exec=env PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-<version>-openjdk/bin${PATH:+:$PATH}" your_program
```

Or, alternatively, using the GUI, adjust its "Properties" → "Application": "Command" field.

---

If you *really* want to allow a user to run `sudo archlinux-java` without being prompted for a password, you can add

```
your_user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/archlinux-java
```

to your `/etc/sudoers`, *after* any already present `your_user` lines. Remember to use `visudo` to do that: it checks the `sudoers` file for errors before saving it, reducing the risk of making `sudo` unusable.

Further reading:

- [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/315749)