# Selectively enable sudo without password

Tags: sudo

On my Ubuntu system I followed the [instructions for enabling sudo without a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password).

It is working well, or should I say too well.

I have a couple of users, say userA and userB, who have been added to the sudo group.

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo userA
sudo usermod -aG sudo userB
```

I did `sudo visudo` and I added the following line at the bottom (i.e. the very last line):
`userA ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

However, I am finding that sudo without password is enabled for both userA and userB.

---

**Question:** How can I enable sudo without password for userA, but not userB?

Comment: Post your `/etc/sudoers` and any file you changed in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Presumably you added `NOPASSWD:` to another line. Note that [if multiple rules apply, the last one counts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).

Comment: does the rule defining `%sudo` (i.e. the rule for members of group sudo) also have `NOPASSWD`?    or do you have a line with `Defaults exempt_group=sudo`?   You added both users to the sudo group, and (from `man sudoers`) *"Users in this group are exempt from password and PATH requirements."*