# Passwordless sudo does not seem to be working

Tags: linux, sudo

I am running Centos 8.

I have used various instructional documents, such as the below:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-sudo-without-password-on-centos-linux/

in an attempt to be able to ssh to an account, and then get to root without having to use a password. I am accessing my machine via passwordless ssh with a key that requires a passphrase.

Once I have logged in, with my account, I want to be able to sudo to root without a password.

Is that even possible?

What I have done is logged in as root (Which DOES require my account password) and then:

```
visudo
```

And added this line here for the account for "Keith".

```
keithchegwin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Now, for "good measure" I have started sshd again, and logged back in as `keithchegwin` fully expecting to be able to do:

```
su root
```

With no password, but it still asks for a password for the account I am logged in as. I want it to stop!

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

I did see his other question here, but that refers to running a specific script or program, not accessing an account with no password so I do not think this is a duplicate:

[How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` and `su` are two different commands, and do different things.

`su` on its own won't do passwordless.

With your setup, you could do something like `sudo su` and it won't ask for a password.  Or, more simply `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`.

Comment: `sudo -i` is recommemded. WIth `sudo -s` you may not get the extra system path for root.

Comment: Tried it, thanks, it still asks for the password of the user I have accessed the server as...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo su root`.
Also, you only want to enter `root` privileged shell, the next command is worked too: `sudo -s`.
Difference between both, `sudo su root` inherits all currently environment variables, `sudo -s` equals `sudo "$SHELL"`.
For example, in `sudo -s`, if your default shell is `/usr/bin/zsh`, you'll be the same as `sudo "/usr/bin/zsh"`.

Comment: Use `sudo -i` instead of the clunky `sudo su root`