# Enable a group of commands to be run as sudo, without using sudo directly

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I have recently started looking into Salt Stack and have installed a master Salt agent on an ubuntu VM.

To sun my commands when I am logged in I need to always use

`sudo salt ....`

Is there a way to enable the Salt to be ran with sudo by default? Meaning I don't need to type in the sudo password or use sudo at all.

I am new to linux so I apologise if this seems like a sily question. Thanks in advance

Comment: add an alias or shell function to your non-root account or write a script...

Answer (score 2):

You can create shell functions or wrapper scripts that run `sudo` for you. E.g.  put a script like this in your `$PATH` (perhaps in `$HOME/bin`):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /path/to/tools/salt "$@"
```

You may want to put the actual binaries somewhere *outside* the user's `PATH`, so they don't get called directly by accident. Then just make the necessary `sudo` configurations to allow the user to run `/path/to/real/salt` instead.

If you like, you could make a more generic wrapper too, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo "/path/to/tools/${0##*/}" "$@"
```

It takes the name of program to call from the name it was itself called as, so if called as `pepper` or `/usr/local/bin/pepper` it would run `sudo pepper`, and so on. Then you can symlink the various names to that same script.

To configure `salt` to run without a password, you can follow the instructions given here: [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/170373).

Comment: Would doing this mean I have to type in my sudo password at all?

Comment: @user564693, that's controlled by the `sudo` config, look for the `NOPASSWD:` option there.

Comment: @user564693 you can configure `sudo` to allow specific commands to be run with no password. So after you do what this answer describes, follow the instructions here: [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13058)