# Call 'ps' as a normal user in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, ps

A brief introduction to my question: the command `ps` will print the information of system processes.

But when I login as **root** and change the permission `x` of `ps`

```
chmod -x /bin/ps
chmod u+x /bin/ps
ls -l /bin/ps 
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root ...... ps
```

Then I create a new shell script file `call_ps_via_root.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ps
```

and set the `x` permission

```
chmod +x /bin/call_ps_via_root.sh
ls -l /bin/call_ps_via_root.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ...... call_ps_via_root.sh
```

After this, I login with a normal user **sammy**, and I type `ps`, it will print

```
Permission denied
```

and I type `/bin/call_ps_via_root.sh`

It is still denied. How can I make it work by `call_ps_via_root.sh`?

Comment: Incidentally, why do you first go to such lengths to make sure only root is allowed to run `ps` and then turn around to try and give users limited root rights for the purpose of running `ps`? Not criticizing, just wondering what exactly you're trying to accomplish here -- maybe we'll figure out a better way to do itt than this...

Comment: First,I want nobady to use `ps` except **root**;second I want to call `ps` indirectly via some method like calling **call_ps_via_root.sh**.And I can give different permission to different user by **setgid** to **call_ps_via_root.sh**

Comment: ... You *really* need to take a good long look at `sudo`. And possibly reexamine exactly what you intend to do and what you hope to accomplish with it, because I really fail to see how restricting `ps` usage is going to help secure your system given that all it does is provide a useful interface to read out information readily available in `/proc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't: if you make `/bin/ps` only executable by root, it will be only executable by root. You can't just wrap a script around it to bypass the permission check.

**set-user-id**

If you want that a normal user calls `ps` as root you have to look at the set-uid permission. From the [setuid article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on Wikipedia:

> setuid and setgid (short for "set user ID upon execution" and "set
>   group ID upon execution", respectively)[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) are Unix access rights
>   flags that allow users to run an executable with the permissions of
>   the executable's owner or group. They are often used to allow users on
>   a computer system to run programs with temporarily elevated privileges
>   in order to perform a specific task. While the assumed user id or
>   group id privileges provided are not always elevated, at a minimum
>   they are specific.

See also the man page of chmod

**sudo**

If instead you want a normal user to execute something executable by root only use [`sudo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). It will allow you to configure which user will be able to execute what.

Answer (score 3):

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root ...... ps
```

This says that the user who owns it has read, write, and execute permission, and all others just read. So nobody but root can execute `ps`.

The script you wrote is executable by all, but inherits the permissions from the one who invokes it, so he also gets the "permission denied" when trying to execute the `ps`, as he is still a normal user.

My guess is that you want to prevent regular users from executing `ps` with certain options (not that it makes sense to me), but then you have to add the `setuid` bit or `setgid` bit to your script (see man page of `chmod`). When you do this it gets the permissions not from the invoker of the script, but from the one who owns the script.

**BUT BEWARE**: Setting the `suid` bit on scripts is inherently insecure. You can do very much with environment variables, that e.g. tell the shell to execute commands - and then they are executed as root (here a custom c-program with the sticky bit is the better solution).

**EDIT**: Another solution would be to use `sudo`. Here you can also configure which parameters are allowed to a `sudo`ed program.

**EDIT2:** Why I think it is not a good idea to prohibit user just from executing `ps`? As far as I know, all the information `ps` outputs can be also be acquired via the `/proc` system - so if you do nothing else it is just security (or whatever you want to achieve) by obfuscation.

Comment: +1 for sudo.  That is the *correct* way of doing privilege escalation.

Comment: Regarding setuid shell scripts (a bad idea indeeed), see [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364) . @ChrisSmith Even `sudo` needs to be done right. In particular, when giving limited permissions, make sure that `sudo` only allows a few whitelisted environment variables through.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's better to use 'sudo'. If you don't have sudo installed and configured

```
su - someuser -c "/yourscript.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to grant users access to information that is only available using root-tools without giving the user root privileges via `sudo`.
For example to provide the information of a `smartctl -A` without providing access to the full functionality of `smartctl`.

Consider for example the program `hddtemp`. It reads the temperature of a given hard drive from the S.M.A.R.T. data of the drive and prints it to stdout. While you normally need root privileges to do so, it also provides a daemon mode, s.t. the program would run as root, wait in the background for non-root client requests, and forward the output to them whenever they connect the socket. In this fashion you could implement a daemon (started as root) that runs `ps` and redirects its output whenever the client wants.

Consider this Python example (may need to be ran as root):

```
import socket, subprocess

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50006

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ps"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    for line in pipe:
        conn.send(line)
    conn.close()
```

you may then put a `netcat localhost 50006` in your `call_ps_via_root.sh` and you are done.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that you have full control over the channel for privilege escalation requests. The downside is that you have to manage your own authentication. If you want to allow a user to run `smartctl -A` only, configure `sudo` to allow him to run `smartctl -A` only.