# Setuid bit seems to have no effect on bash

Tags: linux, bash, setuid

I was experimenting a bit and noticed something strange: setting the setuid bit on a copy of bash located at `/usr/bin/bash-test` seemed to have no effect. When I ran an instance of `bash-test`, my home directory was not set to `/root` and when I ran the `whoami` command from `bash-test`, my username was not reported as being `root`, suggesting that `bash-test` was not running as root. However, if I set the setuid bit on `whoami`, I was reported as being root in any shell, as expected.

I tried setting the setuid bit on `/usr/bin/bash` as well and observed the same behavior.

Why is bash not running as root when I set the setuid bit on it? Could selinux have something to do with this?

Comment: you find additional info about the setuid in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364/33055) question.

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](https://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2017/readings/setuid.pdf) by Chen, Dean and Wagner. Its an old paper but it still applies.

Comment: relevant  https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-18276

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The explanation is kind of annoying: bash itself is the reason. `strace` is our friend (must be SUID root itself for this to work):

```
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1001
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 1001
setuid(1000)                            = 0
setgid(1001)                            = 0
```

bash detects that it has been started SUID root (UID!=EUID) and uses its root power to throw this power away, resetting EUID to UID. And later even FSUID, just to be sure...:

```
getuid()                                = 1000
setfsuid(1000)                          = 1000
getgid()                                = 1001
setfsgid(1001)                          = 1001
```

In the end: no chance. You have to start bash with UID root (i.e. sudo).

**Edit 1**

The man page says this:

> If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are  ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.

But this does not work for me. `-p` isn't even mentioned among the startup options. I also tried `--posix`; didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

In any case, a SUID root program *does not* run with root's environment (`$HOME`, configuration for the shell, whatever), it runs with root *powers* (i.e., it can delete any file, change any permissions, etc).