# Why is the suid bit having no effect on a shell or perl script?

Tags: scripting, setuid

As an experiment in playing with the suid bit, I tried writing a script to run `apt-get update` from a bash script, and then set the suid bit on it, so I could just run `~/update` or something.

`apt-get update` could be anything here - some program that listens on a privileged socket, or writes to `/` or anything else that has to be run as root. Please don't latch on to `apt-get update` here.

First try is this, which didn't work, failing with `can't get lock, are you root?`. The reason would seem to be [Setuid bit seems to have no effect on bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash).

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
```

So I thought I'd try to bypass the shell, but this didn't work either, for the same reason.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("apt-get", "update").
```

I've got the permissions correct (afaik) - `sudo chmod 4755 ~/update`.

Have I misunderstood setuid, or am I just missing something simple?

Comment: Related: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Comment: See `sudo strace -fe execve apt-get update`, how many of those applications do you think are safe in a privilege escalation context with untrusted environment? Don't use `setuid` for that, you need to isolate the client. Provide with a service instead (where `apt-get` is run in a trusted context upon the client's request, instead of `apt-get` being called in the client's context). Could be as simple as using `inetd`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm just using apt-get update as the first thing that came to mind that required sudo. The problem is the suid bit, not the practical value of the script.

Comment: @MrBones, and I'm saying that only small, heavily reviewed, very safe sections of code should run with setuid. A shell or generic interpreter like perl, let alone apt-get, let alone a shell script don't fall in that category. At least you can make it a bit safer by using `sudo` that does a bit of sanitizing on the environment. Best is to use a service approach. setuid should only be considered as the last-resort approach.

Comment: But how am I supposed to learn using the `suid bit` if you shut down my questions when I attempt to experiment with it? If I say I'm mucking around in a VM, will that satisfy you?

Answer (score 1):

`suid bit` is disabled for **scripts** in most *linux and unix* distributions because it opens several security holes.

However, native commands and binary executables can be used with `suid bit`.

Answer (score 0):

for this to work, try

```
cp /bin/bash /bin/mybash
chmod 4755 /bin/mybash
```

and use `/bin/mybash` as shebang ( `#!/bin/mybash` on first line) for your script.

you sould avoid this on production systems.

Comment: That effectively gives anyone (and anything) root access on that machine.

Comment: You need `#! /bin/mybash -p`, otherwise `bash` will drop its privileges.