# Why does setuid not work?

Tags: linux, root, chmod, privileges, setuid

I want to ensure that my program can only be run by user `xyz` using root privilege. To do this, I set the setuid bit with:

```
chmod u+s program1.sh
ls -l program1.sh
rwsr-x--- 1 root house 1299 May 15 23:54 program1.sh
```

Also, I added user `xyz` to the `house` group so that only `xyz` and root can run program1.sh.

In program1.sh there is

```
id -u
```

so that it can show me the effective ID.

Running `program1.sh` as root, it shows `root`. But running with the `xyz` account, it shows **`xyz`**. It seems that it didn't run with root privilege. I don't know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When executing shell scripts that have the setuid bit (e.g., perms of rwsr-xr-x), the scripts run as the user that executes them, not as the user that owns them. This is contrary to how setuid is handled for binaries (e.g., /usr/bin/passwd), which run as the user that owns them, regardless of which user executes them.

Check this page: https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/124693

This is a security measure taken by operating system. You should use your script with **sudo** instead.

If you really need to use setuid o your script you can create a binary that will do the work. Create a new file “program.c” and copy the following code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
     
   int main()
   {
     setuid(0);
     system("./program.sh"); #This line is dangerous: It allows an attacker to execute arbitrary code on your machine (even by accident).
     return 0;
   }
```

Compile and execute the code using the following commands:

```
$ gcc program.c -o program
$ sudo chown root.root program
$ sudo chmod 4755 program
$ ./program
```

This way it will work. The setuid works for compiled file, and this file can execute others files as root.

Comment: great information

Comment: It's a beautiful thing!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly

Comment: Great hack! You saved my afternoon :)

Comment: Please note, that this solution is dangerous, as long as the user can edit or replace `./program.sh`. This would enable every user who can execute `program` to run arbitrary code as the user who owns `program`. From my point of view, a safer solution would be to port the code from `./program.sh` directly into C code and add it to `program.c`.

Comment: Great hack indeed, which allows ANY USER to run ANY COMMAND as root </sarcasm-tag>

Comment: Please note, that this solution is dangerous,  a user does not even have to replace `./program.sh`. This would enable every user who can execute program to run arbitrary code as the user who owns program. It runs `./program.sh` in the present working directory.

Comment: @VicenteBolea The code is dangerous. It allows execution of arbitrary code: make an executable `program.sh` is any directory. Then run `Path/to/that/program`.

Comment: @ElasticThoughts The code is dangerous. It allows execution of arbitrary code: make an executable `program.sh` is any directory. Then run `Path/to/that/program`.

Comment: @MarcusThornton The code is dangerous. It allows execution of arbitrary code: make an executable `program.sh` is any directory. Then run `Path/to/that/program`.

Comment: The link to redhat site is broken.

Comment: So essentially, setting set-id is useless when executable shell scripts is executed directly?