# ssh-add is always asking for passphrase - Automate it on bashrc

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-agent

I want to add to my bashrc the code:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but it is always asking to

**Enter passphrase for /home/User/.ssh/id_rsa:**

A friend of mine add the same snippet to bashrc and worked perfectly(without asking for passphrase and showing the message **Identity added: /home/User/.ssh/id_rsa**.

How can I do it in a way that I don't have to type the passphrase each time I entry on terminal and show me the info that Identity added?

Comment: You can add those command to a script with no password needed and call that script on your bashrc. It's a workaround but probably not the best way. Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506683/execute-shell-script-without-password/506688

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply. But my friend added the same "code" to bashrc file and worked without asking for password

Comment: It seems your private key is encrypted. Does `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` prompt for a password? If so, you would need to unencrypt or pass the password via a script (insecure).

Comment: Your friend may be using a key without a passphrase. You can remove the passphrase from your key if you're not concerned with the security implications.

Comment: The unique difference is that he is using ubuntu 18.04 and I am using ubuntu 20.04. WSL from Windows store I mean

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of `ssh-agent` is to enable you to add your keys and passphrases **once** so you won't have to type them again as long as the machine is running. You don't need to run `ssh-add` in your `bashrc` - you only need to run it once in your shell to type the passphrase, and as long as your `ssh-agent` is running, it will keep the decrypted key in it's memory and you won't have to type the passphrase again. You only need to keep the `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` line in your `bashrc`.

The reason it asks for a passphrase in the first place, is that when you create a new ssh key (using `ssh-keygen`), it asks the user for a passphrase. You can leave it empty to indicate that you don't want to encrypt your key, but if you do type a passphrase, you'll have to type it any time you'd want to use the key in the future (again, that's **exactly** where `ssh-agent` comes in handy).

The difference between you and your friend is that your ssh key is probably protected by a passphrase, and your friend's key is not.

As [@FelixJN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686703/ssh-add-is-always-asking-for-passphrase-automate-it-on-bashrc#comment1298041_686703) wrote in the comment, you can run `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to confirm it asks for a passphrase. If your friend runs it, it probably won't ask for it because his key is not encrypted.