# What does `ln /path/to/file -i` do in a setuid'ed script?

Tags: bash, setuid, ln

I was making a Bash script with the setuid permission on, but it didn't work. So I found my solution here:

- [Why does setuid not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/why-does-setuid-not-work) and
- [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Now my script works fine and all (I rewrote it in cpp).

To satisfy my curiosity as to why pure Bash shell didn't work, I read this link: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html (referenced by this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910). At that site, I came across the following:

```
        $ echo \#\!\/bin\/sh > /etc/setuid_script
        $ chmod 4755 /etc/setuid_script
        $ cd /tmp
        $ ln /etc/setuid_script -i
        $ PATH=.
        $ -i
```

I don't understand the fourth line, which reads `ln /etc/setuid_script -i`.

What does that command do?

I've read in the `ln` manual that `-i` is just the "interactive" flag (asking whether you want to overwrite an existing file or not). So why does `ln /etc/setuid_script -i` followed by `PATH=.` and `-i` make my shell execute `/bin/sh -i`?

Comment: Related: [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `ln /etc/setuid_script -i` is intended to create a hardlink to a file called `-i` in the current directory. You might need to say `ln -- /etc/setuid_script -i` to make this work if you are using GNU tools.

The shell can get commands to run in 3 different ways.

1. From a string. Use `sh -c "mkdir /tmp/me"` with the `-c` flag.
2. From a file. Use `sh filename`
3. From the terminal, use `sh -i` or `sh`.

Historically when you have a shell script called `foo` starting with `#!/bin/sh` the kernel invokes it with a filename, i.e. `/bin/sh foo`, to tell it to use the 2nd way of reading commands. If you give it a filename of `-i` then the kernel invokes `/bin/sh -i` and you get the third way.

There are also race conditions. This was exploited thus.

1. The `exec` system call is invoked to start the script.
2. The kernel sees the file is SUID, and sets the permissions of the process accordingly.
3. The kernel reads the first few bytes of the file to see what kind of executable it is, finds the `#!/bin/sh` and so sees it is a script for /bin/sh.
4. The attacker replaces the script.
5. The kernel replaces the current process with /bin/sh.
6. The /bin/sh opens the filename and executes the commands.

This is a classic [TOCTTOU (time of check to time of use)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) attack. The check in step 2 is against a different file to the one used (in the open call) in step 6.

Both these bugs are usually fixed these days.

Comment: so the ```nice -20 temp &``` in the page is intended to execute ```temp``` script, but with very low scheduling priority (20), so that it's put off later by the scheduler; then ```&``` tell it to run in background (so the attacker can enter the ```mv my_script temp```). Then when the shell is busy changing permission/user who execute the script, the attacker already changed the ```temp``` script with his/her own. Is this correct?

Comment: And therefore when I use compiled binary (instead of interpreted shell script), this problem (race condition) won't occur since the binary is loaded into memory and not read line-by-line from disk. Is this correct?

Comment: The problem is not usually the `line by line` reading, A `mv` will replace the file atomically.  The issue is that the kernel starts the shell and then the shell opens the filename. With a suid binary the kernel does the open itself. Edited my answer to explain the attack more.

Answer (score 3):

The document you linked to (http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html) is describing the behavior of `ln` on a (presumably) UNIX system, and you looked at the manual in a Linux system, or more precisely a GNU/Linux. The GNU is the relevant bit here. GNU `ln` does indeed have the option you mention:

```
   -i, --interactive
          prompt whether to remove destinations
```

However, this is a GNU extension and is not part of the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) where only the following option flags are defined:

```
-f
    Force existing destination pathnames to be removed to allow the link.
-L
    For each source_file operand that names a file of type symbolic link, create a (hard) link to the file referenced by the symbolic link.
-P
    For each source_file operand that names a file of type symbolic link, create a (hard) link to the symbolic link itself.
-s
    Create symbolic links instead of hard links. If the -s option is specified, the -L and -P options shall be silently ignored.
```

So, since `-i` isn't a valid option for `ln`, the command `ln /etc/setuid_script -i` will actually make a hardlink named `-i` which points to `/etc/setuid_script`. Next, the command `PATH=.` redefines the `PATH` variable to only search for executables in the current directory which now means that `-i` will execute the file named `-i` in the current directory which, as it is a hardlink to `/etc/setuid_script`, will execute the script instead. However, since this is a shell script, the actual command run will be `/bin/sh -i`.