# How do I run a sudo command from kde shortcuts command?

Tags: permissions, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, settings

In KDE setting you can assign a shortcut to execute your arbitrary command.

To assign a command to shortcut in KDE, you can do the following. In `System Settings` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Custom Shortcuts`, right click, choose `New` -> `Global Shortcut` -> `Command/URL`. Go to `Action` tab and fill in the command. And in `Trigger` tab assign the actual shortcut. And this mechanism works normally for the non-sudo commands.

[image]

But unfortunately, when I use the command that needs root privileges (let's assume `sudo systemctl start something`), it is just not executed.

Is there a way to bypass this limitation? I want to be able to trigger action, that requires evaluated permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use an executable, which is owned by root and has a SUID bit.

Most likely, you do not have your own binary and instead you want to use a command. If you make your bash script file with suid bit, suid bit will be ignored, see [Why does setuid not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/why-does-setuid-not-work).

So, for your command you need to compile a binary.

Create the file `start_smth.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    
int main()
{
    setuid(0);
    system("systemctl start something");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it and set permissions:

```bsh
$ gcc start_smth.c -o start_smth
$ sudo chown root:root start_smth
$ sudo chmod 4755 start_smth
```

In the Command/URL field in settings fill in the path to the start_smth binary file, for example `/home/user/bin/start_smth`.

[image]

---

If you have many commands you need to prepare in such way, you may use this script `compile_and_set_permissions.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"
FILE_NO_EXT="${FILE%.*}"

gcc "$FILE" -o "$FILE_NO_EXT"
sudo chown root:root "$FILE_NO_EXT"
sudo chmod 4755 "$FILE_NO_EXT"
```

Then pass a c files as a parameter:

```
$ compile_and_set_permissions.sh stop_smth.c
```

Comment: Amazing, ty. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **name of your terminal emulator** (for example Konsole) with -e flag, and then add your command:

```
konsole -e sudo systemctl start something
```