# Why setuid does not work on executable?

Tags: permissions, executable, setuid

I know that enabling setuid on scripts has security issues and so is inactive by default, but expect that it works for executables.
I created and executable which shows uid as an output following instructions described in this post: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

But it returns same uid (1000) both before and after running`sudo chmod +s ./setuid-test`. I think this means that setuid does not have any effects on my executable, why and how to solve?

The source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%d", geteuid());
    return 0;
}
```

Built and run with

```
$ gcc -o setuid-test setuid-test.c
$ ./setuid-test
1000
$ sudo chown nobody ./setuid-test; sudo chmod +s ./setuid-test
$ ./setuid-test
1000
```

When running `ls -la`, this is what I get:

```
me@me:~$ ls -la setuid-test
-rwsrwsr-x 1 nobody me 8572 Aug 19 16:39 setuid-test
```

Comment: Is the executable owned by a user other than the one you're running it as?  (setuid doesn't mean change to root; it means change to the user that owns the executable.)

Comment: PHPLearner I think you need to involve a group/user in order to change the SUID of a file

Comment: @cjm `me@me:~$ ls -la setuid-test` ----returns----
`-rwsrwsr-x 1 nobody me 8572 Aug 19 16:39 setuid-test`

Comment: Your program works as expected on my Ubuntu 14.04 system if it's in my home directory, but not when it's in /tmp, because the parameters used to mount /tmp forbid setuid programs. Where is your program located?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the file (setuid-test) is located in a sub-folder in home directory.

Comment: Type `df .` in the directory to find the mount point, then `mount | grep nameofmountpoint`. Is there a `nosuid` flag listed there?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `mount | grep /home/me` returns  
`/home/me/.Private on /home/me type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=xxx,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=0123456789abcdef,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=fedcba9876543210)`

Answer (score 10):

Most filesystems designed for Unix/Linux can be mounted with a `nosuid` attribute, which will prevent setuid or setgid binaries located on those filesystems from altering the effective uid or gid of a process. It's often used when mounting "untrusted" filesystems, those that are under the control of a non-administrator.

In your case, the filesystem you're using is type ecryptfs, which according to [askubuntu: Error when running binary with root setuid under encrypted home directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/210091/212231) enforces nosuid (and nodev) automatically, starting with the versions from a few years ago.

Here is a description of the reason for the change, from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2012-3409 :

> Vincent Danen     2012-07-20 11:25:56 EDT
>   It was reported that the private ecryptfs mount helper (/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private), which is setuid-root, could allow an unprivileged local user to mount user-controlled ecryptfs shares on the local system.  Because the ecryptfs helper does not mount filesystems with the "nosuid" and "nodev" flags, it would be possible for a user to mount a filesystem containing setuid-root binaries and/or device files that could lead to the escalation of their privileges.  This could be done via a USB device, if the user had physical access to the system.
>   ...
>   Forcing MS_NOSUID and MS_NODEV mount flags was added to version 99 .

Comment: If the system allowed a user to mount a file-system that allows setuid, then it would be trivial to become root. 1) create an executable 2) elsewhere `chown root`, `chmod +s` 3) mount it 4) run executable

Answer (score 2):

SetUID bit on executable allows to run executable at file **owner** (not superuser). To be able to run executable as root, execute:

```
sudo chown 0:0 ./setuid-test
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not the issue. It's possible to have a program that's setuid to a user other than root. In the scenario in the question, `setuid-test` should display `nobody`'s UID.

Comment: @Gilles You are right. I expect that setuid-test displays `nobody`, not `root`

Comment: "SetUID bit on executable allows to run executable at file owner" and my file owner is `nobody`, thus I expect `65534` in return, but I see `1000` whoever be the owner!

Comment: Check the mount options of the filesystem on which your test program runs. If it is mounted with `nosuid`, then your program can't possibly work.

Comment: @countermode @MarkPlotnick `mount | grep /home/me` returns  
`/home/me/.Private on /home/me type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=xxx,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=0123456789abcdef,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=fedcba9876543210)`