# setuid not working

Tags: permissions, filesystems, users, setuid

I was trying to learn how `setuid` works.

So I made a dummy program which just prints the current user:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    cout << system("id -a") << "\n";
    cout << system("whoami")  << "\n";
}
```

I compiled and created the executable `my-binary` under the user `anmol`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 anmol anmol 9972 Feb  1 16:54 my-binary
```

Then, I set the `setuid` option using `chmod +s`:

```
-rwsrwsr-x 1 anmol anmol 9972 Feb  1 16:54 my-binary
```

If I execute it normally, I get the following output:

```
uid=1000(anmol) gid=1000(anmol) groups=1000(anmol),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),122(sambashare)
anmol
```

Now, if I change to another user using `su user2`, and then execute it, I get:

```
uid=1001(user2) gid=1001(user2) groups=1001(user2)
user2
```

And when I execute it using `sudo ./my-binary`, I get:

```
uid=1001(root) gid=1001(root) groups=1001(root)
root
```

As far as I understand, no matter how I run it, should I not get the 1st output everytime?

I checked other similar questions over here and some suggested me to check if the filesystem is mounted using `nosuid` option, so I executed `mount | /dev/sda1` and got the output:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Which means that this option is not enabled.

Any hints on why am I not getting the expected output?

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate of the second and third questions, which are using set-UID on shell scripts, not on compiled binaries as in this question here.  An answer to those involves wrappers that defeat the script interpreter's behaviour.  An answer to _this_ involves re-writing the program at hand to better do the simple task that its author wants, which is not in fact done by the answer to the first question.

Comment: @JdeBP happy to defer to you in this instance. 2nd and 3rd suggested links now removed

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`?!?  [That's a bad idea.  Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. I did it just because its a dummy program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system(3)` library function runs its command argument by passing it to `/bin/sh -c`, and the `/bin/sh` on Linux (either `bash`, `dash` or `mksh`) gives up any setuid or setgid privileges unless called with the `-p` option.

The bash manpage says:

> If the shell is started  with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the `-p` option is **not  supplied** [...] the effective user id is set to the real user id.

With `dash` (the `/bin/sh` from Debian/Ubuntu), this is *kind of new*: it wasn't yet the case in Debian 9 Stretch (2017), and it's only a Debian-specific [change](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869#34), still not in the upstream [sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git) as of 2020-02-04. `bash` has had this since its 2.X versions (first included in RedHat 7.X, 2000).

This is **still not the case** with other shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, etc) or with the `/bin/sh` from other systems (OpenBSD, FreeBSD, Solaris; but not NetBSD where it was [changed](https://marc.info/?l=netbsd-source-changes&m=143267612230150) to work like bash).

If they have it, their privileged mode works **differently** than in bash: it's turned [on](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/sh/options.c?revision=326025&view=markup#l98) by default when the shell is run in setuid mode, and you have to turn it [off](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/sh/options.c?revision=326025&view=markup#l287) with `set +p` in order to have the shell drop the setuid privileges.

---

If you want to use `system()`, `popen()`, or run a shell or an executable shell script directly from your setuid binary, then you should give up any "split personality" and completely switch over to your real or effective credentials via `setres[ug]id`:

```
% cat a.cc
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    uid_t euid = geteuid();
    setresuid(euid, euid, euid);
    system("id");
}
% c++ a.cc
% chmod u+s a.out
% ./a.out
uid=1002(fabe)
% su -c ./a.out
uid=1002(fabe)
```

---

If you want just to check that your binary really switched its effective credentials, do it directly, not by invoking an external program via `system()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    uid_t euid = geteuid(); struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(euid);
    cout << "euid=" << euid;
    if(pw) cout << ", " << pw->pw_name;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's new. See the [possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369883/100397) and the two other links I've suggested

Comment: Yes, it's new. It wasn't the case with the default shell in Debian 9. And check the formatting of "*new*".

Comment: @roaima At this has NOTHING to do with setuid scripts. Read again, the OP created a setuid binary by compiling a C program.

Comment: It has everything to do with the system(3) call and `/bin/*sh`.

Comment: I was talking about the irrelevant "setuid scripts" links that you dropped (second and third); they have nothing to do with `system()` or this bash feature.

Comment: I think we'll have to disagree. I believe they are all relevant to the issue as described: that putting a setuid bit on a wrapper script and then calling system('/bin/sh...') is not a sufficient way of getting setuid privilege carried through to the destination application.

Comment: No, only the first link is relevant. But then your answer goes on and advocates sudo, which ruins everything.

Comment: This is _most definitely not_ new.  The Bourne Again and Korn shells have had the "privileged mode" mechanism for _at least 30 years_.  The `sh` in Debian 9 is the _Debian Almquist_ shell, which (in some versions) does not have this mechanism.  (It has now.)  On the other hand, this answer is better than roaima's inasmuch as the right thing here is to _stop using `system()`_ for stuff that is dead simple to write in in-process code.

Comment: @JdeBP the change in dash is only in Debian, not upstream: if https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/log is really the upstream (it looks active). This is the bug report which resulted in the change: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869

Comment: I explicitly wrote "Debian Almquist". Claiming that this is new, as this answer _still erroneously does_, is the illogic of claiming that something is new because it wasn't in _a completely different thing_ to the thing where it has existed for >30 years. It's also ahistoric and Debian-myopic. There have been many cases where `sh` on Linux operating systems has been the Bourne Again shell. Switching to the Debian Almquist shell and _losing_ this decades-old behaviour, then to _regain_ it, is the relatively recent thing in the lifetime of Unix and Linux, which did not happen on (say) Fedora.

Comment: @JdeBP The only erroneous thing was the bogus claim that the privileged mode in the Korn shell ever worked the same as in the Bourne Again shell -- with the implication that `system()` would work the same if `/bin/sh` were ksh instead of bash or dash. That claim wasn't in my first version -- I had added it because of your comment ;-) Feel free to fact-check the corrected version.