# SETUID not effective when calling cat from AWK script from C program

Tags: awk, acl, setuid

Consider the following simplified example which illustrates my problem.
The server's OS is Debian 11 armhf.

we're in directory `/botm/test/`:

```
drwx------ 2 b b 4096 Sep 27 19:27 hide
-rwsr-xr-x 1 b b 8260 Sep 27 19:54 test1
-rwsr-xr-x 1 b b 8264 Sep 27 19:58 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b b   56 Sep 27 19:52 test1.awk
-rw-r--r-- 1 b b  172 Sep 27 19:54 test1.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 b b  186 Sep 27 19:58 test2.c
```

As can be seen, only the owner, `b` can access the directory `/botm/test/hide`.

We are now user `test`
We can not access the file `/botm/test/hide/test.txt`:

```
$ cat hide/test.txt
cat: hide/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Ok. The programs `test1` and `test2` have the SETUID bit set.
So even if we are the user `test` we can run these programs as if we were user `b`.

First, `test2.c`:

```c
/* test2.c */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int r;
  r = execl("/usr/bin/cat","/usr/bin/cat","/botm/test/hide/test.txt", (char *)0);
  printf("%d\n",r);
  return r;
}
```

```
$ ./test2
hidden content
$
```

As expected, it works.

Now, `test1.c`, `test1.awk`:

```c
/* test1.c */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int r;
  r = execl("/usr/bin/mawk","/usr/bin/mawk","-f","/botm/test/test1.awk", (char *)0);
  printf("%d\n",r);
  return r;
}
```

```c
# test1.awk
BEGIN {
  system("cat /botm/test/hide/test.txt");
};
```

```
$ ./test1
cat: /botm/test/hide/test.txt: Permission denied
$
```

Surprisingly, this does not work.

What I expect:
If I run the program `test1` which has SETUID, then it should run as if the user `b`.
So if the program calls `/usr/bin/mawk` then that too should run as user `b`.
So if the awk script then calls `cat`, then `cat` should also run as user `b`.
So `cat` should be able to access `/botm/test/hide/test.txt` which is available only to user `b`.
But this does not happen.

Some real context now.
This above was just a simplified example. I have a project with multiple C and AWK programs. The AWK programs are called from the C programs to process some text and generate some output. This includes sometimes calling `cat` or other system tools. Some of these programs are run from the Apache server as the user `www-data` which does not have access (and shouldn't have) to some of the temporary files created by these programs. That's why SETUID is used. And this kind of workflow is used a lot in this project (from 2014).

I'm now moving this from my old server (where this worked) to a new one (where this doesn't work).
Changing the project to not rely on this mechanism would be a very big redesign which I don't want to do now.

Why is SETUID not preserved when a C program (with SETUID) calls an AWK script which calls a system tool (`cat`, ...)?
What to do to preserve it again?
On a previous version of the system it worked.

EDITED TO ADD:

I verified that the AWK program still has access to the hidden file, only things called by `system()` don't.

So I found out that the reason of this behavior is that when using `system()` (or `getline` with a pipe) then `mawk` calls `sh` to perform the command.
AWK doesn't have `exec` or anything like that.

`sh` will drop the SETUID unless called with `-p`.
This is new behaviour. This part of `man sh` is not present on my old server:

```
           -p priviliged    Do not attempt to reset effective uid if it does not match uid. This is not set by default to help avoid incorrect usage by
                            setuid root programs via system(3) or popen(3).
```

So to make my programs work again I have to achieve at least 1 of these things:

- make `/usr/bin/sh` not drop SETUID by default.
- make `mawk` or other compatible AWK interpreter use `-p` when using `/usr/bin/sh` for `system()`
- find a different way to run programs from AWK
- redesign all the programs to not rely on this. For example do them in C, Perl, or Python which do have proper exec functionality not relying on `sh`.

Redesigning the entire project (and some other projects which also use this workflow) would take effort and time which I currently don't have so I really need to restore the full SETUID functionality somehow.

Actually, the functionality of `cat` can be easily recreated inside the AWK program but also other tools are called with `system()` in my project: `[ -f`, `cat`, `cp`, `mkdir`, `mv`, `sleep`, `wget`.
And in most cases calling them without SETUID is not acceptable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setuid root does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369883/setuid-root-does-not-work)

Comment: Also related - [setuid not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565251/100397)

Comment: @roaima thanks for the links.  
First link: does show the reason but the proposed solution is not relevant to my situation.  
Second link: Since my AWK scripts are always called from C programs, the trick with `setresuid` looks promising. I will try it.

Comment: If the only thing you need root privileges for is cat(1), you can instead read and output the file directly from your C program, as you noted in the edit with regards to awk(1). In such a case there is no need for `execl` and much less awk.

Comment: It looks like half of this question is a (partial) answer, so should probably be moved out of the question and into an answer of its own.  And perhaps that leads to a follow-up question.  (As a bonus, you'll earn reputation from all three posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer to similar problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565254/543092
There is a proposition to use `setresuid()`.

Since in my project the AWK scripts are always called from C programs this is a solution available to me.

I do something like this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uid_t euid;
    int r;
    euid = geteuid();
    r = setreuid(euid, euid);
    if (r != 0)
        return (r = errno);
    r = execl("/usr/bin/mawk","/usr/bin/mawk","-f","/botm/test/test1.awk", (char *)0);
    printf("%d\n",r);
}
```

This way the "disguise" is complete and `sh` will have no idea that there was a SETUID before. Everything works.

And this is a better solution than somehow making `sh` always behave as if there was `-p`. It will preserve my SETUID if I know what I'm doing.

I use `setreuid()` instead of the `setresuid()` proposed there because:

- `setreuid()` is enough
- `setresuid()` is a GNU extension.

Comment: And of course I can do the same for group id.