# How to enable a non-root user to empty the linux buffer cache

Tags: debian, permissions, cache, setuid, buffer

I'm required to empty the linux buffer cache in a python script, that runs on a Debian wheezy VM.

As root I run `sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, but the script is run by a user, without root privileges.

I've thought of the following possibilities:

- give the user write permissions on the file `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
  (which doesn't seem to work, as I get Operation not permitted when I `chmod 646 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`)
- Set the setuid on `tee`, which should work but then the user could go *apesh*t* with `tee`
- I could setuid on the script and remove write permissions for the user to write to the script, so he couldn't alter it (but then again, that's bad, as the user may interact with the code)
- or I could write a tiny bash script featuring only the *empty the linux buffer cache* process, then remove write/read permissions, setuid and add execution permission for the user

What is the sanest way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your list, only the fourth possibility (writing a small setuid script in a safe directory e.g. `/usr/local/bin` not changeable by the user) might work and could be safe, but is nowadays often [disabled by the distribution.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/15241)

The easier and better option is to add the following line to /etc/sudoers (use e.g. `visudo` for this)

```
YOURUSERNAME     ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=3
```

and then include the line

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=3
```

in your script.

Comment: Purely for future readers - unfortunately, you cannot SUID a bash script in Linux as explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts). `sudo` will work fine though.

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks, I added this to the answer.