# Darwin strips setuid from interpreter in hash bang execution

Tags: osx, setuid

This is not exactly a question about how to run a hash bang *script*.

In this situation, a hash bang script exists which doesn't (necessarily) have the `u+s` permission. Rather, the interpreter has `u+s`, and the script designates that interpreter: `#!/path/to/interpreter`.

On Mac OS, in this situation, the designated interpreter *itself* isn't granted the setuid implied by its *own* permission bits, as it would be if it were directly executed. Its real and effective user ID is just that of the user who ran the hash bang script.

Is there a workaround for this **not involving the interpreter re-executing itself?**

Re-executing works:

```
Kazs-Mac-Pro:txr kaz$ uname -a
Darwin Kazs-Mac-Pro.local 11.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Fri Apr  8 20:29:42 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.36~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Kazs-Mac-Pro:txr kaz$ cat setuid.tl
#!./txr --reexec
(put-line `gids: @(getegid) @(getgid)`)
(put-line `uids: @(geteuid) @(getuid)`)
(put-line `groups: @(getgroups)`)
(seteuid 0) ;; throws if unable
Kazs-Mac-Pro:txr kaz$ ls -l txr setuid.tl
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      163  5 May 15:18 setuid.tl
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1334500  5 May 15:17 txr
Kazs-Mac-Pro:txr kaz$ ./setuid.tl 
gids: 20 20
uids: 0 501
groups: 20 402 401 12 33 61 79 80 81 98 100 204
```

All that `--reexec` does is call `execvp` on the program's path name, and the remaining arguments after `--reexec`. Poof, setuid privs are back. This is ugly, though.

If we do not have `--rexec`, this is the behavior:

```
Kazs-Mac-Pro:txr kaz$ ./setuid.tl 
gids: 20 20
uids: 501 501
groups: 20 402 401 12 33 61 79 80 81 98 100 204
./txr: unhandled exception of type system-error:
./txr: seteuid failed: 1/"Operation not permitted"
./txr: during evaluation at ./setuid.tl:4 of form (seteuid 0)
```

(The `u+s` on the script is irrelevant from the system perspective; the interpreter uses that, and the ownership of the script, to decide whether to run the script setuid, or whether to permanently drop privileges and then run it.  Of course, we wouldn't want to do this sort of thing with an interpreter that isn't aware of setuid operation and blindly confers its elevated privilege onto any piece of code that it is asked to execute.)

Answer (score 0):

Most Unix variants disable setuid on scripts for security reasons. For more information, see [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Earlier versions of OS X had a setting to allow setuid scripts: `sysctl kernl.sugid_scripts=1`, but [I don't see it documented on 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html). I don't know if it still exists but isn't documented, and if it still exists I don't know if it's secure.

The usual way to run a setuid script is through `sudo`, which takes care of some of the security problems with setuid scripts, in particular sanitizing the environment. Add a sudo rule (run `visudo` to edit the sudo configuration):

```
ALL ALL = (target_user : target_group) /path/to/script
```

This allows anyone to run `sudo -u target_user -g target_group /path/to/script …` (with any arguments). Replace the first `ALL` by `%original_group` to allow only the members of `origininal_group` to do this.

If you want this to be transparent, write a wrapper script that invokes `sudo` as desired:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo -u target_user -g target_group /path/to/script "$@"
```

Comment: I added `--rexec` option to the interpreter (described in updated question).  I was wondering whether there is an efficient way not involving intermediary process images. Like some switch we can just flip somewhere.  The script is a bit of a red herring here because it's just an argument to the interpreter. The interpreter (a binary written in C) isn't being run with setuid (regardless of the permissions on the script).

Comment: I will look into that `sugid_scripts` setting; maybe it influences this behavior too. Or perhaps at least renders it irrelevant, in any case.

Comment: @Kaz `kern.sugid_scripts` is the switch to flip, *if* it's still supported and it's secure. Many Unix variants don't have such a switch, for example Linux doesn't. The script is *not* an argument of the interpreter if you use shebang, that's only one possible implementation; for setuid scripts to work, the script *must not* be passed as an argument to the interpreter (`/dev/fd/3` is used instead, see the question I link). There's nothing wrong with using an intermediate process image, that's the Unix way of doing things.

Comment: I've noticed that Solaris passes /dev/fd/3 if the script is setuid. If not, the name is passed. Linux doesn't support setuid scripts, but if an interpreter is setuid, it is honored through hash ban execution. The extra process image makes numerous extra system calls related to shared lib attachment, C library startup and memory management.

Comment: For all the security theatre, **OSX allows a rwsrwxrwx binary to be setuid!**