# How to execute root command scripts from not root user with SUID use?

Tags: sudo, non-root-user

I want to execute a script embedding commands requiring a root user from my not root account without sudoing:

`/usr/local/bin/dodo`

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sync && /usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid
```

What I did is making it root and setting the SUID bit:

```
chown root:root /usr/local/bin/dodo
chmod a+xrs /usr/local/bin/dodo
```

But when I try to execute it, the result is:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/dodo
This utility may only be run by the root user.
```

I have tried also a sudoer solution by adding the file `/etc/sudoers.d/dodo`:

```
%family ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/dodo
```

Which is supposed, if I am not mistaken, to authorise users of group family to execute dodo as root without password. But the result is the same.

What do I miss please? I am on Debian Jessie

EDIT: In the last case, `sudo dodo` works without password

Comment: On Linux (and other UNIX-like systems), scripts do not honor the setuid bit for very very good reasons. See [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link of AlexP and the different answers there, here is what works fine:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/dodo
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sync
exec sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid
```

_

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/dodo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 laurent family 60 déc.  18 17:47 /usr/local/bin/dodo
```

_

```
cat /etc/sudoers.d/dodo 
%family ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid
```

Then for anyone in the family group:

```
dodo
```

executes sync and pm-suspend-hybrid without password nor sudo