# Is a php file with SGID bit and read-only & execute a security problem?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security, php

I find php files with **SGID bit and read-only & execute**. The group is **root**. Is this a problem?

Because a user will need to run the php interpreter with their our account, could it led to privilege escalation?

Like, the user **www-data** runing **php** as **www-data** and call the file with **SGID bit**, could he became root?

```
php path/to/file.php
```

Comment: Linux? The kernel has been configured by default to ignore both `setuid` and `setgid` of any interpreted executable script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; sgid:root will run the file as root if run directly on an OS with sgid-on-!# enabled, and if the php file can be tricked into writing to an arbitrary file due to lack of input sanitation, etc.

That's a big IF but defence in depth is advised because bugs are plentiful..

Test suid;

```
./test.php && whoami
root
www-data
```

Where test.php contains

```
#!/usr/bin/php
echo exec('whoami');
```

[Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Notes how modern implementations deal with interesting ways to take advantage of sgid

https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#setuid

Notes the #! simlink attack was an issue from 1983 to 1993 before which shebang wasn't supported and after which it was more securely implemented.

Comment: Are sure? GUID set for script.....

Comment: @user1133275, are you referring to a case where the OS applies setuid/setgid even on interpreted scripts? You might want to make that explicit, since AFAIK that's not very common. Even so, surely they wouldn't run the script as root (the user), if it only has the set_gid_ bit set? And if that happens, then surely the script runs with root's GID regardless of input sanitization problems?