# What is difference between file mod status 750 and 2750?

Tags: permissions

In some material to describe `SGID` ,when any user executes a file with SGID bit set on it, it will always be executed with the group ownership of that file, irrespective of who is running it.

```
sudo groups arch1
arch1 : arch
```

User `ach1` belong to the group `arch`.

```
arch@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ cat  /tmp/myarch.sh
whoami
arch@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ chmod 750   /tmp/myarch.sh
arch@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ ls -al   /tmp/myarch.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 arch arch 8 Aug 23 17:22 /tmp/myarch.sh
```

Execute it in `arch` account,the output is `arch`.
Execute it in `arch1` account,the output is `arch1`.

```
arch@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ chmod 2750   /tmp/myarch.sh
arch@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ ls -al   /tmp/myarch.sh
-rwxr-s--- 1 arch arch 8 Aug 23 17:22 /tmp/myarch.sh
```

Execute it in `arch` account,the output is `arch`.
Execute it in `arch1` account,the output is `arch1`,output is not `arch`.

How to understand "it will always be executed with the group ownership of that file, irrespective of who is running it", it is no meaning to set mode `2750`, the mode status `0750` take same effect!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Comment: "This discussion applies equally if you substitute “setgid” for “setuid”; they are both ignored by the Linux kernel on scripts"