# Is there a way to make a shell script always run as root

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I want to know how to create (if possible) a bash script that runs as root on Debian regardless of the user that executes it, without asking for any kind of authentication.

This file will run all its commands as it were the root user, but only the real root user will be able to read it or write on it.

I need this because I want to run commands like `swapoff`, `swapon`, `apt`, etc... But through another application, and I want it to not ask me any password.

The commands will be fixed (those root commands will have their parameters in the file, not as input), so security implications are not exactly my preoccupation, but I accept explanations as well.

Comment: Most likely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts

Comment: [fakeroot](https://wiki.debian.org/FakeRoot) could *perhaps* help here. The idea of file permissions is for this question to have the answer "obviously not".

Answer (score 10):

The low-level way to have a program always run under a particular UID, is the setuid bit on the binary file. That's how e.g. `sudo` and `su` get their root permissions, even if they're usually started by normal uses.
But in general, Unix-like systems don't support setuid *scripts*, see: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

However, what you can do, is to configure `sudo` or some other such tool to allow the users to run some particular files with the appropriate privileges. E.g., this would allow a user named `viceadmin` to run `/usr/local/bin/sudoswapon` with any arguments, and without authentication:

```
viceadmin ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/sudoswapon
```

Now, since `sudo` deals with changing privileges itself, `sudoswapon` can be a shell script.

You're right to note that the script would need to be careful with how it deals with command line arguments, and that *all* the gotchas of the shell language will apply. Luckily, `sudo` filters out most environment variables, at least if the `env_reset` option is set.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot make a bash script that runs setuid. However, you can make use of `sudo` (or similar programs, like calife) to ensure they are run with root privileges.

There are two basic approaches to do this.

Lets suppose your script is called `reset-swap` and does:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
swapoff /dev/sdb
shred -n0 -z /dev/sdb
mkswap /dev/sdb
swapon /dev/sdb
```

**Option A**: would be to let any user to run these individual commands, and prefix them with sudo:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
sudo swapoff /dev/sdb
sudo shred -n0 -z /dev/sdb
sudo mkswap /dev/sdb
sudo swapon /dev/sdb
```

and add on `/etc/sudoers` a series of lines which let everyone do that:

```
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/swapoff /dev/sdb
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: shred -n0 -z /dev/sdb
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: mkswap /dev/sdb
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: swapon /dev/sdb
```

However, while the actions specified may be safe to be done by everyone *as done by the script*, it might not be so independently. For example `mkswap` checks that the swap partition is not mounted before processing it, but `shred` would happily wipe a mounted swap partition.

Thus, it would be preferable to use

**Option B**: let only that script to be run with sudo.

```
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/reset-swap
```

You would then call it as `sudo reset-swap` rather than `reset-swap`. If you get fancy, the script could elevate itself if it wasn't run as root, letting it be run without specifying the `sudo` prefix:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "`id -u`" -ne 0 ]; then
 echo "Switching from `id -un` to root"
 exec sudo "$0"
 exit 99
fi

swapoff /dev/sdb
shred -n0 -z /dev/sdb
mkswap /dev/sdb
swapon /dev/sdb
```

Last, let me finish with a couple of points from the sudo lecture: Think before you type, With great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

It was realized long ago that setuid scripts presented insurmountable security problems (they're easily subverted by fooling with `IFS`), so we don't do that anymore. Linux has been changed to help us avoid setuid scripts.

You can achieve your desires with `sudo`, using `NOPASSWD`. Read `man sudoers sudo`.